# Javascript Variable Reference

Tags: javascript, scope

Something I don't understand, which I'm sure someone with any simple knowledge of Javascript will get;
How does the 'm' variable referenced in this replace function actually refer to the input from the str - I don't understand how it takes the str as m?

```
str = str.replace("whatevers",function(m){ return m.toUpperCase(); })
```

Many thanks in advance. Tyler.

Comment: Worth a look: [Closures/Callbacks in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622421/what-are-the-use-cases-for-closures-callback-functions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each function defines how any functions passed in are used. The [documentation for `String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) explains how it's used in the section on [specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Somewhere in the implementation of `replace`, that function you're passing in is called with several arguments. The full example is:

```
function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string) {
  return "replacement_text";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the context of string replacing, if you pass in a function as the second parameter like the way you're doing, the first argument of that function that you pass in (in your case 'm') will be anything that matches your initial first argument (in this case "whatevers"). Once it finds a match, that gets assigns to 'm', and then it will perform the toUpperCase function on that variable 'm'.