# Need to get the value of a variable which is sent as a string?

Tags: javascript

I'm sending a string as parameter to a function, but i already have a global variable in that name, i want to get the value of that variable but its sending as undefined..

My example code

i have a array as reg[0][0],reg[0][1],reg[1][0],reg[1][0],reg[2][0],reg[2][1]

and i have some global variables as tick1, tick2, tick3...

it will either have the values as 0,1 or 2

and in a function i called

```
calc_score(id) //id will return as either tick1,tick2,tick3
{
    alert(eval("reg[id][1]")); // it should return the value of reg[0][1] if id is 0

}
```

But its not working.

The id wont be a numeral it will be string .. So how can i do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh! You change the code like the following:

```
calc_score(id) //id will return as either tick1,tick2,tick3
{
    alert(eval("reg[" + id + "][1]")); // it should return the value of reg[0][1] if id is 0

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its really interesting to know that a downvoted answer solves a problem. Really amazing.

Comment: Generally people see downvotes in different ways, sometimes as a method to indicate an incorrect answer, sometimes to mark down the answer to improve visibility of other answers.  In this case it's probably a disagreement that this is the best solution to the problem (because of the use of `eval()`). Nevertheless, let me even it out a bit for you.

Answer (score 6):

You [shouldn't use eval](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx) for things like this.  If you need to convert `id` to a number, use the unary `+` operator:

```
calc_score(id) //id will return as either tick1,tick2,tick3 
{ 
    alert(reg[+id][1]); // it should return the value of reg[0][1] if id is 0 
}
```

or `parseInt()`

```
calc_score(id) //id will return as either tick1,tick2,tick3 
{ 
    alert(reg[parseInt(id, 10)][1]); // it should return the value of reg[0][1] if id is 0 
}
```

---

If you need to parse a string like "tick1, tick2" then you have a few options.  If the first part will always be "tick", you can slice the end off the string like so:

```
calc_score(id)
{
    id = +id.slice(4);         // or +id.substring(4) if you prefer
    alert(reg[id][1]); 
}
```

If `tick1, tick2, tick3` are global variables, then instead of using `eval()`, you should reference them via the window object like so:

```
calc_score(id)   //id will return as either "tick1","tick2","tick3"
{
    alert(window[id]);
}
```

Comment: +1 for unary + for conversion, which I've never heard of before.

Comment: @OregonGhost: It's essentially the same as using `Number()` to cast, but shorter and useful in so many situations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript/2243631#2243631

Comment: i forgot to emphasize "The id wont be a numeral it will be string .. "
The id will be a string but it contains a number value, so how can i do that?

Comment: The id will be like 'str1' , 'str2' etc.. The var str1 will always have nos.. I've denoted this under the code but not clearly and bold enough to catch the notice. Sorry ..

Comment: @Vijay, sorry I misunderstood that part.  See my update at the bottom.

Comment: @Vijay: Thanks.  I've added another update because I finally understand what you were asking for :-) `eval()` is not the right tool for the job here, but you should be able to access global variables via the window object: eg. `window[tick1]`.

Comment: All object properties in Javascript are strings; lookups with numbers are implicitly converted to strings.  `reg[1]` is the same as `reg['1']`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
alert(reg[Number(id)][1]);
```

of course you should check that `id` can be cast to a number before you do it. I don't really think you need the `eval`, unless you are trying to do something else that you haven't mentioned.