# Accessing javascript function properties before they are defined?

Tags: javascript, function, properties

I was reading through this thread: [Hidden Features of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript)
and found this post: [Hidden Features of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript/61260#61260)

I was playing around with the code in firebug and I found that this bit of code seems to work fine:

```
var fn = function(x) {
   console.log(this.foo);
}
fn.foo = 1;
```

How come I can access the property of the function before it's assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value `1` is not from console.log(this.foo),

Its from `fn.foo = 1`, firebug just return last value in its console

Try this, you will see also 1 too

```
fn=function(){}
fn.foo = 1;
```

Comment: Oh I see. So is this a firebug glitch or is this javascript doing something funky?

Comment: @Yansky: Neither. It's feature-by-design. The last return value is always printed.

Answer (score 1):

Because that function isn't executed when you assign it to `fn`. A variable is resolved in execution time.

Even without the `fn.foo = 1;` line, getting an undefined property from an object returns `undefined` anyway. That's not an error.

Also, `this.foo` will not print 1 when you run `fn()`, because `this` inside the function does not point to the function `fn`, but `window`, or the instance that receives a `new fn()`.

Answer (score 0):

if it was not defined you could access it anyway, it would just have the value `undefined`.

I guess you call `fn(x)` after the `fn.foo = 1;` statement. if you call it before, you will log `undefined` after, you log `1`.