# In jQuery, should i use parseFloat(el.width()) or parseInt(el.width(),10)? which one is more preferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, parseint, parsefloat

I always had this question: 
When i dont mind the exact floating number

Which one is preferred?

#### parseFloat

```
    someValue  = parseFloat(el.outerWidth())+parseFloat(ele2.css("marginRight")),
```

#### parseInt

```
    someValue  = parseInt(el.outerWidth(), 10)+parseInt(ele2.css("marginRight"), 10),
```

Which method is easier for the JS engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as broad as it's long really.  `parseFloat` is pointless here because the values will always be integers.  I'd rather save on bytes and use the [unary operator `+`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript/2243631#2243631):

```
someValue  = (+el.outerWidth())+(+ele2.css("marginRight"));
```

Answer (score 3):

When you're doing: `el.outerWidth()` jQuery is already returning and integer, [see the docs for return types](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/).  So in this case, there's no need to parse the width at all.

It should be noted, there's another overload of `outerWidth(bool)` that includes the margin if you want left and right margins, you can just do this if that's the case:

```
someValue = el.outerWidth(true);
```

Comment: correct in case of outerWidth(), but my question is general, anyway thanks.  good point.

Comment: @adardesign - In that case...you can't position any more accurately than a pixel, makes no sense to since that's what monitors display in.  For layout properties in pixels, use `parseInt(val, 10);`

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is of course Andy E's solution, but to answer your question:
I think `parseFloat` is pointless if your number have not a floating-point, so I would use `parseInt`.

The size of the variable is an important factor in those performance comparisons, but `int` and `float` take up the same space in the memory (4 bytes), so it dosen't really matter. In addition, `parseFloat` seems to do more calculating and string-parsing than `parseInt`.

Comment: +1 Alon, "this" is the answer i really wanted to hear, the others where practical solutions to my question, "you" answered the question