# Why are items in the wrong cells in this Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Somebody wrote this (very terrible) function to translate a numeric value from 0-999 to English words.

```
function getNumberWords(number) {
  var list = new Array(1000);
  list[000] = "zero";
  list[001] = "one";
  list[002] = "two";
  list[003] = "three";
  ///skip a few
  list[099] = "ninety nine";
  list[100] = "one hundred";
  list[101] = "one hundred and one";
  ///skip a few more
  list[997] = "nine hundred and ninety seven";
  list[998] = "nine hundred and ninety eight";
  list[999] = "nine hundred and ninety nine";
  return list[number];
}
```

There is some rather odd bug in here that I can't seem to figure out the cause of. Some, but not all of the elements are placed in the wrong cell.

I tried displaying the contentes of the list and it showed a pretty funky result:

```
> list.toString();
"zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,
fifteen,sixteen,seventeen,twenty,twenty one,twenty two,twenty three,twenty four,
twenty five,twenty six,twenty seven,thirty,thirty one,thirty two,thirty three,
thirty four,thirty five,thirty six,thirty seven,forty,forty one,forty two,"
///(skip a few)
"sixty six,sixty seven,seventy,seventy one,seventy two,seventy three,seventy four,
seventy five,seventy six,seventy seven,,,,,sixty eight,sixty nine,,,,,,,,,
seventy eight,seventy nine,eighty,eighty one,eighty two,eighty three,eighty four,"
///(and so on)
```

That is, elements 0-7 have the expected value. Elements 68, 69, and 78-999 also have the expected values. Elements 64-67 and 70-77 are empty. Elements 8-63 have incorrect values.

What in the world is going on here? Why are 15 cells empty, 56 cells incorrect, and the rest correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numeric literals starting with `0` are interpreted as *octal* values (if they can be) — that is, numbers in base-8. This is the case in [Javascript](http://rx4ajax-jscore.com/ecmacore/more/literal.html#octal), [C](http://c.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html), [C++](http://cpp.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html), [PHP](http://codepad.org/CZJmOc6V), [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber.html), [Bash](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/numerical-constants.html) and many other languages.

Now, base-8 `22` is base-10 `18` so you're not accessing the elements that you think you are. Your first eight array elements were fine because, naturally, base-8 `0` is also base-10 `0`, and so on up to `7`. A value like `069` did not cause confusion because it *cannot* represent anything in base-8, so Javascript falls back to base-10. Yuck!

---

I suggest using spacing for alignment instead:

```
function getNumberWords(number) {
  var list = new Array(1000);
  list[  0] = "zero";
  list[  1] = "one";
  list[  2] = "two";
  list[  3] = "three";
  ///skip a few
  list[ 99] = "ninety nine";
  list[100] = "one hundred";
  list[101] = "one hundred and one";
  ///skip a few more
  list[997] = "nine hundred and ninety seven";
  list[998] = "nine hundred and ninety eight";
  list[999] = "nine hundred and ninety nine";
  return list[number];
}
```

I also suggest making a new function that generates the strings on-the-fly; it shouldn't be taxing and certainly no more so than creating this array on every call.

Comment: `22` octal is actually `18` in decimal, but it's the nineteenth element since arrays are zero-indexed.

Answer (score 4):

In Javascript `022` means `22` in octal (`18` in decimal).

[Octal numeral system on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)

Comment: To complete the thought -- 22 in octal is 2*8 + 2 = 18 in decimal, which is the 19th element of the array (since the first element is at index 0).

Comment: @Ted Thanks, added the result to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Starting a number literal with a `0` in non-strict code may cause that number to be parsed as an Octal literal (base 8).  For instance, `010` is parsed to a number with the value `8`.

Octal literals are now deprecated and will not be parsed as octals in strict mode, using `"use strict"`:

```
function a() {
    alert(010);
    // -> 8
} 
function b() {
    "use strict";
    alert(010);
    // -> 10
}
```

Not all browser support strict mode, so for now just change your code to make sure numbers do not start with a 0, or wrap them in strings:

```
list[  21 ] = "something"
list["022"] = "something else";
```

Strings work because octal numbers [are not coerced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547836/why-doesnt-an-octal-literal-as-a-string-cast-to-a-number).

Comment: Not always. If JavaScript can't coerce to octal it will coerce to decimal.  For example, `08` coerces to `8`.

Comment: @Paul: sorry about that.  I was writing quickly because I knew I was in a race ;-) Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The 0-prefix means octal in JavaScript, so `022` is octal:

```
022 = 2*8^1+2*8^0 = 18
```

And since the first index i 0, 18 gives the 19th element.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, numbers beginning with `0` are interpreted as octal (base 8).

For example, `010 === 8`.

Oddly, JavaScript will interpret the number as decimal (base 10) even if it has an octal prefix, if the number is impossible to reach in octal.

For example, `08 === 8`.

Comment: That is one of the reasons octal literals were deprecated.  Not only are they confusing, this quirk makes them doubly so.  They should have thrown an error from the start.