# addEventListener pass caller as argument

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have the following code. My problem is that when clicking, the event is firing but the argument passed is not the correct one. It is passing the last dynamically created row i.e. `dataStructure.length` value. Anyone knows a solution how to get around this?

```
var table = document.getElementById('output');                  

for(i =0; i<dataStructure.length; i++){
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.setAttribute('id', i);
    var url = dataStructure[i].url;
    
    if(document.addEventListener)
        row.addEventListener('click', function(){handleRowClick(i);}, false);
    var obj = dataStructure[i];
    var cellCount = 0;
    for(field in obj){
        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.setAttribute('id', cellCount++);
        //cell.addEventListener('click', function(){window.open(dataStructureObj.links[i].url);}, false);
        cell.innerHTML = obj[field];
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    cellCount = 0;
    table.appendChild(row);
}           
}

function handleRowClick(rowClicked){
    var rowHTML = rowClicked.innerHTML;
    var cells = rowHTML.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(cell in cells)
    {
        alert(cell.value);
    }
    window.open(cells[1].innerHTML); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` in the `function(){handleRowClick(i);}` is the loop variable `i`. When the function gets called, the loop is long-finished and `i` holds the last value it did at the end of the loop, *not* the value it held when you created the `function(){}`.

This is the closure loop problem. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function) for solutions using either closures or `Function#bind`:

```
row.addEventListener('click', handleRowClick.bind(window, i), false);
```

However, you're not really using that `i` at the moment. It would be easier to say:

```
row.addEventListener('click', handleRowClick, false);
```

and then use `this` to retrieve the row:

```
function handleRowClick(){
    window.open(this.cells[1].innerHTML);
}
```

(Side note: unfortunately if you add `attachEvent` backup in order to support IE<=8, it doesn't get `this` right, so you'd still be looking at closures/bind to get the object you want.)

also:

```
    for(i =0; i<dataStructure.length; i++){
```

Missing `var`: `i` is an accidental global.

```
        row.setAttribute('id', i);
```

Avoid `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` in HTML documents. They don't do what they should in IE. Use the DOM Level 2 HTML properties instead, they're more reliable and more readable: `row.id= i`.