# JS variable scope missunderstanding

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem:
slideHelpers.total = 4

```
for (i=1;i <= slideHelpers.total; i++) {
    $('<a href="#">' + i + '</a>').bind('click', function(){ alert('go to the ' + i + ' slide')}).appendTo('.slideaccess')
}
```

the alert gives out 5 what is logic, because when the function click triggers i is actually 5. But i would like to have the same i as in my `<a>` tag. What is the best way to handle this?

I could put i in the data() of the `<a>` tag for example but i am sure there is a easier way.

Comment: Welcome to today's Closure Loop Problem question! See eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function and many more for background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i=1;i <= slideHelpers.total; i++) {
    $('<a href="#">' + i + '</a>').bind('click',
        (function(i){
            // Capture i in closure
            return function(){
                alert('go to the ' + i + ' slide')
            };
        })(i)
    ).appendTo('.slideaccess')
}
```

Optimised:

```
var ary = [], i = 0, n = slideHelpers.total,
    open = '<a class="index" href="#">',
    close = '</a>';

// Fill array with numbers: 1,2,3,4,5...
while (++i < n) ary[i] = i + 1;

$('.slideaccess').append(
    open + ary.join(close + open) + close
).delegate('a.index', 'click', function() {
    var index = $.text(this);
    alert('go to the ' + index  + ' slide');
});
```

Comment: `(function(){...})()` acts as a lexical wrapper (or "scope") which is given the **current** value of `i` as an argument. The inner (returned) function is technically a closure, and can see the captured `i`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an additional function that returns your function:

```
for (i=1;i <= slideHelpers.total; i++) {
    $('<a href="#">' + i + '</a>').bind('click',
        (function(i) {
            return function() {
                alert('go to the ' + i + ' slide');
            };
         })(i)
     ).appendTo('.slideaccess');
}
```

With this additional function, the inner `i` in your `alert` refers to the argument `i` of that function and not to the `i` of the outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new scope, otherwise every function will reference the same `i`. In JavaScript variables are scoped to functions.

```
var make_alert_message = function make_alert_message(num) {
    return function () { 
        alert('go to the ' + num + ' slide');
    };
}

for (var i = 1; i <= slideHelpers.total; i++) {
    $('<a href="#">' + i + '</a>').bind(
        'click', make_alert_message(i)
        ).appendTo('.slideaccess')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code example `i` is basically a global variable.  By the time the `alert()` code executes, `i` has the maximum value of the for loop.  The standard way to fix this problem in JavaScript is to create a new function which has its own [scope](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/) to "hold" the variable around.  Take for instance this code which returns your event handling function:

```
(function(i) { // using i as an argument here 'scopes' it
   var something = i; // also within this function scope.
   // inside here, both i and something will only ever reference the "local scope"

   return function() {
     alert(i);
   };
})(i); // and here we are calling that function with i = 1,2,3,...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [eventData](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) of the bind function:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= slideHelpers.total; i++) {
    $('<a href="#">' + i + '</a>').bind('click', { index: i }, function(arg) { 
        alert('go to the ' + arg.data.index + ' slide');
    }).appendTo('.slideaccess');
}
```

Comment: like i told in my question, i am looking for a solution without having to use data().