# Clone a node using JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I want to create a clone for below code using JavaScript DOM:

```
var summaryDiv = __createElement("div","sDiv","sDiv"+j);
        summaryDiv.onmouseover = function() {this.setAttribute("style","text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;");}
        summaryDiv.onmouseout = function() {this.setAttribute("style","text-decoration:none;");}
        if(browser.isIE) {
            summaryDiv.onclick = new Function("__fc.show_tooltip("+j+",'view_month')");
    } else {
            summaryDiv.setAttribute("onclick", "__fc.show_tooltip("+j+",'view_month',event)");
        }
   someobj.appendChild(summaryDiv);
```

I'm using `obj = summaryDiv.cloneNode(true)` which is creating a node, but the `onclick` event is not getting fired in the case of Internet Explorer. Can anybody help me over it?

Comment: Instead of doing setAttribute('onclick'), why not just assign a function to the onclick property?

Comment: i m creating multiple div using loop and using setAttribute i m assigning some value which i m passing into show_tooltip function

Answer (score 2):

```
this.setAttribute("style","text-decoration:underline
```

Don't use setAttribute, it won't work in IE<8 for many cases (including this one) and the HTML/CSS-DOM properties are more readable: `this.style.textDecoration= 'underline';`.

(These days you may want to use a CSS `:hover` rule instead of JS hover-highlighting. It's only IE6 where arbitary-hover doesn't work; the last remaining IE6 users can often do without the shiniest stuff as long it it still works. They're probably used to seeing broken web sites by now...)

```
    if(browser.isIE) {
        summaryDiv.onclick = new Function("__fc.show_tooltip("+j+",'view_month')");
    } else {
        summaryDiv.setAttribute("onclick", "__fc.show_tooltip("+j+",'view_month',event)");
    }
```

No need for nasty old browser sniffing (avoid!) as the first of those will work in all browsers. However, creating a function from a string is really ugly. You can use a function literal instead:

```
summaryDiv.onclick= function() {
    __fc.show_tooltip(j, 'view_month');
};
```

However if you're doing this in a loop (over `j`?) you may be subject to the [Closure Loop Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function). You can get around that with another closure, but ECMAScript Fifth Edition's `Function#bind` is cleaner:

```
summaryDiv.onclick= __fc.show_tooltip.bind(__fc, j, 'view_month');
```

[Adding bind to browsers that don't yet support it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function/2569493#2569493)

> but onclick event [on clone] is not getting fire in case of Internet Explorer.

Yeah, it's normal for event handlers not to get copied when cloning. (Actually, it's usually IE mistakenly cloning listeners added via attachEvent that's the problem, so that's the other way around.)

If you want to retain the event handling after cloning you'll have to do it manually:

```
newClone.onclick= oldNode.onclick;
```

Comment: Hi bobince ,i have tried assigning of event(onclick) to new clone but still for IE its not working  i mean i can see through web developer tool in IE8 that event(onclick) is set it for that element but it not firing ..one more details I want to share is, in  my program both clone as well as old object are present in document and inner element have the same id ...please help me i m just confuse over it

Comment: Please post the new code! (eg. pastebin.com et al.) You will certainly have difficulty retrieving elements by ID if you've got duplicate IDs.