# How to access this variable in an inline function?

Tags: javascript, copy, inline-functions

Here is my dilemma.

I've got this section of code:

```
var list_of_numbers = new Array();

function AddToArray(func)
{
    // Add to the *beginning* of the array
    // essentially reversing the order

    list_of_numbers.unshift(func);
}

function DisplayNumber(num)
{
    document.write(num);
}

for(var i=0;i<5;++i)
{
   AddToArray(function() { DisplayNumber(i); });
}

for(var i=0;i<5;++i)
{
   list_of_numbers[i]();
}​
```

What is supposed to happen is that 5 inline functions will be added to the array - each *taking a copy of `i`*. However this does not happen.

**Expected output:**

> 43210

**Actual output:**

> 01234

Comment: @Michael: I don't get what you're saying.

Comment: @Michael: I know - that's what it's supposed to do. The problem is that it isn't saving the value of `i` in each iteration of the loop... I think.

Comment: Yes, JavaScript does not ‘save’ values. You have the [Closure Loop Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two separate issues, both related to scope.

```
var list_of_numbers = new Array(); 
function AddToArray(func) 
{ 
    // Add to the *beginning* of the array
    // essentially reversing the order 
    list_of_numbers.unshift(func); 
} 

function DisplayNumber(num) 
{ 
    document.write(num); 
} 
for(var i=0;i<5;++i) 
{ 
    (function(i) 
     { 
         AddToArray(function(){ DisplayNumber(i); });
     })(i); 
} 

for(var j=0;j<5;++j) 
{ 
    list_of_numbers[j](); 
}​
```

1. The anonymous function you're passing to `AddToArray` is bound to the variable `i`, not the current value.  To address this, we create a new function, and pass in the current `i`.
2. JavaScript has function scope, so when you re-declare `i` in the second loop, you're still modifying the same variable.  Thus, we rename it to `j`.

If only the first were an issue, you would get 55555, since all functions would use the same `i`, at that point 5.  However, since you reuse `i` for the second index, `i` is set to the current loop index.

Comment: Ahhhh. I see. The syntax for the `AddToArray` block is very strange! Thanks for your help.