# puzzle: value in clousure is changed

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

I use `http://tile.cloudmade.com/wml/latest/web-maps-lite.js` to geocode.

There is a address array containing around 20 addresess

```
addresses[n] = {where:where,who:who,contact:contact,note:note,type:type};
```

Then I loop the array to geocode

```
for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    geocoder2.getLocations(addresses[i].where, function(response) { //a callback
       return function(k){
       Lat[k] = response.features[0].centroid.coordinates[0];
       Lng[k] = response.features[0].centroid.coordinates[1];
       latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat[k], Lng[k]);
        MarkerArray[k] = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: latlng,
          zIndex: k,
          title: addresses[k].who,
          icon: icons(addresses[k].type.trim())
        });}(i) // a closure function called
    });
}
```

But the it always works on the final index. Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Closure Loop Problem. You appear to be trying to fix it by adding the `return function(k)...` closure, but that's all occurring inside the callback function, so it won't execute until the loop has exited and `i` is pointing at its final value.

You would have to push that wrapper out a level so it's directly inside the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    geocoder2.getLocations(addresses[i].where, function(k) { //a callback
        return function(response){
            Lat[k] = response.features[0].centroid.coordinates[0];
            Lng[k] = response.features[0].centroid.coordinates[1];
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat[k], Lng[k]);
            MarkerArray[k] = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: latlng,
                zIndex: k,
                title: addresses[k].who,
                icon: icons(addresses[k].type.trim())
            });
        }
    }(i)); // binding *here* instead!
}
```

Or use [Function#bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function/2569493#2569493) to avoid the nested function.

Comment: Your wrapper out solution works in Firefox, but in IE and Chrome....still got the same problem. I will take some time to look into the bind solution