# Closures in a for loop and lexical environment

Tags: javascript, closures

Simple case: I want to load several images which have a common name and a suffix, e.g: image0.png, image1.png, image2.png ... imageN.png

I'm using a simple for loop:

```
var images = [];
for (var i=1; i<N; i++) {
    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].onload = function () {
        console.log("Image " + i + " loaded");
    };
    images[i].src = "image" + i + ".png";
}
```

What I'm getting in the Console is:

```
Image N loaded
Image N loaded
Image N loaded
...
Image N loaded
```

But what I want should be like this:

```
Image 0 loaded
Image 1 loaded
Image 2 loaded
...
Image N loaded
```

Why is this happening?
How can I get my desired behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `i` inside your function is evaluated when the function is *executed*, not when you assign it to `onload`. Your for loop has already completed by the time any of your `onload` functions fire, so all of them see the final value `N`.

To capture the current value of `i`, you need to pass it as a parameter to another function where it can be captured as a local variable:

```
function captureI(i) {
    return function () {
        console.log("Image " + i + " loaded");
    };
}

var images = [];
for (var i=1; i<N; i++) {
    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].onload = captureI(i);
    images[i].src = "image" + i + ".png";
}
```

This works because every time you call `captureI`, a new local variable is created for that instance of `captureI`. In essence, you are creating `N` different variables and each `onload` function captures a different instance of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it in a closure to avoid to use `i` variable, which is a loop variable and thus changes:

```
(function(j) {
  images[i].onload = function () {
      console.log("Image " + i + ", " + j + " loaded");
  };
})(i);
```

This demonstrates the difference between `i`, which is a loop variable and changes, and `j`, which is a function-bound parameter, which doesn't change.

See the jsfiddle here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/VuLTa/

Answer (score 0):

Your loop counter variable has been overwritten already. Check out [this](http://xkr.us/js/closures) FAQ entry explaining exactly why it happens and how to work around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable `i` is declared outside the scope of the loop, it retains its final value after the loop has completed. The anonymous functions you're creating then all bind to this variable, and when they're called, they all get the same final value of `N`.

There's a good discussion of this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function).

Comment: this will give N-1 for all images :-)