# Using a loop variable inside a function, javascript scoping confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have built a dropdown menu system, everything works when tested independently, the problem I have is in the code below. I use the jQuery ready function to build the menu bar from an external array (menubar[]). Here I am trying to get the mouseover event to call the dropdown() function, but using a different argument for each anchor tag.

So rolling over the first should call dropdown(0), the second dropdown(1) and so on.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i in menubar) {
        var declaration = '<a href="' + baseurl + '/' + menubar[i].url +
                          '" class="menutitle">' + menubar[i].name + '</a>';
        var a = $(declaration).mouseover(function () {
            dropdown(i);
        }).mouseout(function () {
            activeTimer = setTimeout("removedropdowns()", 100);
        });
        $("#menu").append(a);
    }
});
```

The code is calling dropdown(6); on each rollover. How can I pass the loop variable (i) into the mouseover function as a literal/static value!

I got this working fine in FF by using

```
.attr('onMouseOver','javascript:dropdown('+i+');')
```

but that wasn't firing for some versions of IE, so I switched to the jQuery mouseover, which fires, but I have the issue above :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(menubar).each(function(i){
        $("#menu").append('<a href="' + baseurl + '/' + menubar[i].url + '" class="menutitle">' + menubar[i].name + '</a>');
    });

    $("#menu a").hover(
        function(){
            dropdown($(this).index());
        },
        function(){
            activeTimer = setTimeout("removedropdowns()", 100);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: thankyou, this worked but I had to subtract 1 from the value returned by index() for some reason.

Comment: Using `$(selector)` inside a loop is a bad practice.

Comment: Also, using a for loop instead of each() is clearly a better choice: `for (var i=0; i < menubar.length; i++) { $menu.append(...); }`

Answer (score 2):

Your actual problem is that each of your mouseover callbacks uses the **same** `i` you increase `i` all the way up to 6, the callbacks still point to the same `i` and therefore all use `6` as the value.

You need to make a copy of the **value** of `i`, you can do this by using an *anonymous function*.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // you should use (for(var i = 0, l = menubar.length; i < l; i++) here in case menubar is an array
    for (var i in menubar) {
        var declaration = '<a href="' + baseurl + '/' + menubar[i].url +
                          '" class="menutitle">' + menubar[i].name + '</a>';


        (function(e) { // e is a new local variable for each callback
            var a = $(declaration).mouseover(function () {
                dropdown(e);

            }).mouseout(function () {
                activeTimer = setTimeout(removedropdowns, 100); // don't use strings for setTimeout, since that calls eval
            });
            $("#menu").append(a);
        })(i); // pass in the value of i
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think that an additional anonymous function is needed here. The mouseover handler already is an anonymous function, so we can capture the current value of `i` via that function: `mouseover(function(i) { dropdown(i); })`

Comment: It still uses the same `i` "reference" and therefore gets the current value of `i` which, after the loop is 6.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: it's not just using an additional anonymous function, it's that the anonymous function is *executed* (see the line with comment "pass in the value of i")

Comment: @Nathan @Ivo Yes, I see. My approach does not work (because the event object is assigned to the first parameter of the handler function)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, if you don't declare your variable, it is defined globally. To fix this, add "var" in front of your i looping variable like this. UPDATE: As Sime noticed (see comment), you also need to pass the variable into the function, otherwise you form a closure on the i.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var i in menubar) {
        var declaration = '<a href="' + baseurl + '/' + menubar[i].url + '" class="menutitle">' + menubar[i].name + '</a>';
        var a = $(declaration).mouseover(function(i) { dropdown(i); }).mouseout(function() { activeTimer = setTimeout("removedropdowns()", 100); });
        $("#menu").append(a);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't thinks that's enough. As @Alberto said, to capture the current value, you have to pass it as a parameter ... like `function(i) { dropdown(i); }`

Comment: @Sime - Good catch. I hadn't noticed that the variable was being captured by the anonymous function. Updated.

Comment: Yea, for every step in the loop, a new mouseover handler function is created which captures the current value of `i`

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `for..in` but rather ordinary loop.

Second, I would just append the links first then apply the events later:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < menubar.length; i++) {
        $("#menu").append('<a href="' + baseurl + '/' + menubar[i].url + '" class="menutitle">' + menubar[i].name + '</a>');
    }

    $("#menu a").each(function(index) {
        $(this).mouseover(function() { dropdown(index); }).mouseout(function() { activeTimer = setTimeout("removedropdowns()", 100); });
    });
});
```

Comment: The for loop is for arrays. The for-in loop is for plain objects. The type of the loop depends on the `menubar` variable (if it's an array or not).

Comment: @Šime yep I know.. judging from the code I strongly believe it's ordinary array.

Comment: Aha, ok :) But I would note that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418326/closures-in-a-for-loop-and-lexical-environment).

> To capture the current value of i, you need to pass it as a parameter to another function where it can be captured as a local variable:

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's `each()` function:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery.each(menubar, function(index, element) {
    var declaration = '<a href="' + baseurl + '/' + element.url + '" class="menutitle">' + element.name + '</a>';
    var a = $(declaration).mouseover(function() { dropdown(index); }).mouseout(function() { activeTimer = setTimeout("removedropdowns()", 100); });
    $("#menu").append(a);
  });
});
```