# Using closures in loop- scope variable

Tags: javascript, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closures in a for loop and lexical environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418326/closures-in-a-for-loop-and-lexical-environment)

I am learning Closures in JavaScript... I saw example of simple code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  document.getElementById('box' + i).onclick = function() {
    alert('You clicked on box #' + i);
  };
}
```

But what exactly happens is that no matter what `div` you select you get an alert about the last `i` - last iteretion.

I saw an solution to that problem with inner function, but why is this happens? doest it's not binding the `onclick` event on every iteretion?

Comment: Search for `[javascript] callback loop last value`. No shortage of duplicates.

Comment: -1 because, since you *know* about closures, this would have been easy to find a duplicate for. Try using the search feature or look at the "similar questions" when creating a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each iteration creates a new function, but each function references **the same** variable `i` (a location in memory). The value of `i` is only evaluated at the time when a handler is executed. That moment is long after the `for` loop finished and at that time, `i` has the value `10`.

[Wikipedia's article about closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) is worth a read and mentions the two ways closures could work: Either by binding the current value of the variable or a reference to the variable itself. The latter is the case with JavaScript.

Comment: That last paragraph is slightly misleading in context. For instance, in both Scala and C# a closure also "binds a reference to the variable". The difference is the scope of a [particular] variable.

Comment: Mmmh, I might have oversimplified a bit but I think it helps to understand the differences, no?

Comment: I'm not saying it's incorrect - and the answer still has my up-vote. It's just a note/nit for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Good old same-variable issue. You can easily circumvent it by passing it through a self-calling function taking `i` as a parameter:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        document.getElementById('box' + i).onclick = function() {
            alert('You clicked on box #' + i);
        };
    })(i);
}
```

The reason why this is necessary and works is that `i` is usually always the same - JavaScript only has a function scope. By using the self-calling function that takes `i` as a parameter you create a new `i` everytime which will be then saved within the closure of the callback function.

Comment: I'd *love* to see a comment from whoever downvoted this.