# Getting the values in a callback function of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am using the jQuery animate method in which I want to call a function when the animation is complete. Since the function is called several times in a loop, I need to access some variable but do not know how to do this (something to do with closures I guess).

I have :

```
while (i<numberofTimeIntervals)
{   
     // some calculations here
     xPos = initialPosX + x + "px";
     yPos = initialPosY - y + "px";

     $("#object").animate({left: xPos},10).animate({top: yPos},10, function(){ console.log(xPos) });  <-- what I want here is the access to xPos and yPos

     i = i + 1;
}
```

So I need to have access to xPos and yPos at the time it is calculated as the callback is called at a later time.

JD.

Comment: You should have the variable there.  It's in the closure's scope... what's it doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass the value (not the reference) of a JS variable to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a second closure:

```
while(i<numberofTimeIntervals)
{
    var xPos = initialPosX + x + "px";
    var yPos = initialPosY - y + "px";

    (function(xPos) {
        $('#object').animate({left: xPos},10).animate({top: yPos},10, function(){  console.log(xPos) });
    })(xPos);

    i++;
}
```

Explanation: JavaScript has no block scope, just a function scope. So your callback function's closure saves the variable (not its value) xPos. So at the end of the loop, the saved variable - which is the same one as the loop variable - has the final value. By wrapping the call in an anonymous function which gets the variable passed as an argument, it's now saved as a new variable which will not be modified anymore.

---

Btw, if you had access to JavaScript 1.7 (unfortunately only few browsers support it) you could also use `let xPos` instead of `var xPos` to move it into the block scope.

Comment: Whoever downvoted: Please leave a comment. From what I know this is the correct way to deal with closures inside of loops.

Comment: JavaScript has no block scope, just a function scope. So your callback function's closure saves the variable (not its value) `xPos`. So at the end of the loop, the saved variable - which is the same one as the loop variable - has the final value. By wrapping the call in an anonymous function which gets the variable passed as an argument, it's now saved as a new variable which will not be modified anymore.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Imo you should put your comment in the answer, makes it even better ;) And I would say it is not a closure as you are not accessing the variables of the parent scope.... but that is nitpick. +1 to compensate -1...

Comment: @felix: added it to my answer

Comment: @JD: since it fixed your issue, please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark icon

Comment: You can't really attribute the lack of `let` support to IE - no versions support it including IE 9 - `let` is a Mozilla extension to the ECMAScript specification which JavaScript is based upon.  FWIW, Chrome and plenty other browsers don't support it either, useful as it may be.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
while (i<numberofTimeIntervals) {   

   //<!-- some calculations here--->

   (function(){
       var 
          xPos = initialPosX + x + "px",
          yPos = initialPosY - y + "px";

       $("#object")
          .animate({left: xPos},10)
          .animate({top: yPos},10, function(){  console.log(xPos) });  
       //<-- what I want here is the access to xPos and yPos

   })();

   i = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a closure there. You should have access to both these variable already. Can you post the exact code pleas?

Comment: No, he will always have the last `xPos` value as the closure. See http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

Comment: Yep, that is what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work this way: http://jsfiddle.net/gailbear/WbNdx/6/

```
function printme(xpos){
    console.log(xpos);
}

while (i < numberofTimeIntervals) {

    var xPos = initialPosX + x + "px";
    var yPos = initialPosY - y + "px";

    $("#object").animate({
        left: xPos
    }, 10).animate({
        top: yPos
    }, 10, printme(xPos));

    i = i + 1;
}
```

The first error I got was "don't define functions within a loop". Let me know if that code helps.

Comment: Sorry to say, but that's completely wrong. You pass the (undefined) return value of a new function instead of a function as the callback. So you execute the function immediately instead of when the callback should be called.

Answer (score -2):

You can define them as global variables, meaning outside of any function or object. Then you can access them from anywhere.