# JavaScript scoping

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following function which constructs one or more y-axes for a Highcharts chart, though my problem has little or nothing to do with the Highcharts API.

```
_constructYAxes: function(yAxes) {

    if (yAxes) {
        var highChartYAxes = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < yAxes.length; i++) {

            var kpiUnits = yAxes[i].units;

            var axisUnits = 'units ' + i;
            var axisLabel = 'label ' + i;

            // construct an Highcharts y-axis object
            var yAxis = {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value + ' ' + axisUnits;
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: axisLabel
                },
            };
            highChartYAxes.push(yAxis);
        }
        // pass all the y-axes to the chart
        this.chartOpts.yAxis = highChartYAxes;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the same `label` is used for each y-axis, even though the `title` is displayed correctly. The difference betweent hese two is that the former is calculated by invoking a function

```
labels: {
    formatter: function() {
        return this.value + ' ' + axisUnits;
    }
},
```

So if I have a chart with 3 y-axes, the label "units 2" appears on all of them.

I think the problem is that the `formatter` function closes over the value of `axisUnits` in the last iteration of the loop, such that when the function is invoked (by Highcharts), it uses the same value of `axisUnits` each time.

What can I do to force the function to use the i-th value of axisUnits each time it is invoked instead?

Clearly my understanding of JavaScript scoping is somewhat lacking (I am frequently surprised by what `this` evaluates to in different contexts). If anyone knows of some good online resources that might help me to get this straight, please send them my way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass the value (not the reference) of a JS variable to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function) and *many, many* others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`axisLabel` is passed as a string directly and does not change.

However, `axisUnits` is *not* directly passed. It's only fetched when the function is called. The problem is that a `for` loop does not create a new scope, so for all iterations there is only one `axisUnits`, which causes all labels to have an equal text.

You can solve this by creating a closure. This way, the string *is* directly passed and "freezed":

```
formatter: (function(x) { // x won't change
               return function() {
                   return this.value + ' ' + x;
               };
           })(axisUnits);
```

Comment: Very nice explanation. If I find out you're really 16 years old and not a native English speaker I'm giving up programming (and speaking)

Answer (score 2):

Use an anonymous function wrapper:

```
formatter: function(units) { //"Private" variable axisUnits
    return function() {
        return this.value + ' ' + units;
    };
}(axisUnits)
```

Because of the anonymous function wrapper, each `formatter` function will now refer to the `axisUnits` variable at the time of creation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right about the closure and the loop problem

Please read here http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62 - does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `function.bind(this, args)`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

It's new and awesome and easy to provide if the browser doesn't have it. So in this case you'd write:

```
formatter: (function(axisUnits) {
     return this.value + ' ' + axisUnits;
}).bind(this, axisUnits);
```

As you can see somewhat less to write than an anonymous wrapping function and easier to understand.

Comment: Actually, this will probably not work as intended because the ``this`` value is being bound to your enclosing object instead of being left as is. So using ``bind()`` for currying only doesn't work and you'll need to create a wrapping function as explained in the other answers. Leaving answer for awareness.