# how to return two functions for onclick event

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pass the value (not the reference) of a JS variable to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function)

i have several links (var a[]) with an onclick event on them. this works well so far by using one function:

```
function setCurrentImage(x) {
    return function() {
        alert("Image: "+x);
        return false;
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].onclick = setCurrentImage(i);
}
```

the thing is, i need two functions. and this code just won't work:

```
function setCurrentImage(x) {
    return function() {
        alert("Image: "+x);
    }
}

function setCurrentNote(x) {
    return function() {
        alert("Note: "+x);
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].onclick = function() {
        setCurrentImage(i);
        setCurrentNote(i);
        return false;
    }
}
```

what is wrong with this code? thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend SLaks's answer:

```
function setCurrentImage(x) {
    alert("Image: "+x);
}

function setCurrentNote(x) {
    alert("Note: "+x);
}
function setOnclickHandler(x) {
    return function() {
        setCurrentImage(x);
        setCurrentNote(x);

        return false;
    };
}

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].onclick = setOnclickHandler(x);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot guys, i works now! happy new year! :)

Answer (score 3):

Each of the functions that you call returns a function, but doesn't actually do anything.
You never call the functions that they return.

Once you fix that, you'll have another problem; all of your inline handlers share the same `i` variable.
You need to wrap that in an IIFE.