# Why does the alert coming from my loop always return the last value, not each iteration value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

I have a some buttons, which are stored in an array. I then loop through that array to add a click event to each button. Each click alerts the value of `i`. I expect the values to be `1`, `2`, `3` and so on, but they always come back as one value, in case `3`.

Can you explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Please see this **[a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fE55Y/)**. Code below:

```
var theButtons = ['.button.one', '.button.two', '.button.three'];

for (i=0; i<theButtons.length; i++) {
    $(theButtons[i]).click(function () {
        alert(i); // always returns 3
    });
}
```

*Please explain it as simply and clearly as you can - I'm somewhat of a beginner at Javascript and programming.*

Comment: Start reading at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function

Comment: why do questions that have been asked a thousand times get upvoted?

Comment: I would say you don't want to code those events in that way anyway...

Comment: @Alvaro You should explain **why** he shouldn't instead of leaving this empty comment there.

Comment: As a programming and especially a javascript beginner, you may want to have a few drinks before you start reading about closures. Your brain will hurt for awhile until you start to understand it.

Comment: @shrewdbeans Does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/fE55Y/6/

Comment: Wow this question has the most amount of answer with down votes I've ever seen...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By the time you click on the button `i === 3`. Need to pass the value of `i` into a closure:

```
for (var i = 0; i<theButtons.length; i++) { // do `var i` so the i is not global
    (function(index){
        $(theButtons[i]).on('click', function () {
           alert(index); // index === the value that was passed
        });
    })(i); // pass the value of i
}
```

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/fE55Y/3/

Comment: I would like to know reason of downvote? Just before i consider to upvote

Comment: @roasted haha I have no idea :-P

Comment: Just one thing, the use of global 'i' should be noted.

Comment: Downvoted due to complaining about jQuery in another answer to the same question yet using a "bloated jQuery function" here.

Comment: .click alias and .onclick alias directly call `.on('click',` - you have added useless bloat.

Comment: @Loktar That's rather vindictive....

Comment: @defaultNINJA true, however he posted this question in the javascript chat to give his downvote attention http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/10714138#10714138 I was not the vindictive one initially.

Comment: @Loktar I was not calling for any downvote attention. I was making a comment, just as many others have over the use of many jQuery functions when they are not needed. All I did was copy/paste the OPs code and explain what was wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks @Neal, this works perfectly. I think I'll need to do some research on closures!

Comment: @shrewdbeans happy to help :-D

Comment: Thank you much :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use EACH method:

```
$( ".button" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).click( function(e){
        alert( index + ": " + $(this).text());
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fE55Y/4/

### Update:

Agreed that `.each()` is not needed for what's been asked. Here's the one without using `.each()` method.

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    alert("Button Index: " + $(this).index());
});
```

Comment: @Neal - well if jQuery is in use anyway using `.each()` isn't adding to any bloat.

Comment: @j08691 This answer is relying on the DOM element's text -- which is useless? Also the op is not ness going through **all** buttons, but he is only going through a set array of buttons...

Comment: He also has his question tagged.. and is using jQuery already. Sure you can do it in pure JS, but theres no reason for this to be downvoted.

Comment: it is adding bloat to the processing... not that it would be noticed, but Neals comment is still kinda valid. however his use of the .click alias is equally as silly.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it's not explaining the problem in th original code, which is at least half of the actual question.

Comment: @Neal - Oh I'm not saying that this is the right answer, I'm just saying that if the OP is using jQuery that I don't see where the bloat came from. If the question didn't use jQuery and this answer suggested it then sure, unnecessary extra code for something that basic.

Comment: Neal, please explain how is it bloated and if it was, why did jQuery developers build such method? And my main point is if you want to write function in pure JS style what's the need of jQuery?

Comment: @Learner That is why there is a normal `.forEach` loop on an array. There is no real reason to use `$.each` especially since it did not even answer the OPs question.

Comment: @j08691 ^^ see above.

Comment: @Neal the questioner has a tag "jQuery" and .foreach is a pure JS function and not jQuery. I saw the tag and provided him the jQuery solution. As for second part "that i did not answer what's been asked" it's a totally different thing and shouldn't be mixed up with $.each conversation.

Comment: @Learner and the `$(this)` selects over and over gain? Cache them!

Comment: Another thing I have been noticing on SO is that some people just Down-Vote without understanding, because someone with higher VOTES is not convinced with your solution.

Comment: @Neal in this example caching $(this) is not actually going to impact performance (much if any).

Comment: @Neal I not trying to prove my point but don't tell me that we are now worried about nanosecond performance hits. If it was so important no one should actually use jQuery.

Comment: You don't even need the each anyway in this case. Just alert the index of the button. `alert( $(this).index(".button") );`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to asynchronous programming and global variables!

The problem you are seeing here is because of the fact that `i` is declared globally in this case, in that is accessible from anywhere by anything.

So, what happens when your script is executed is:

- Loop through the array of classnames
- On each iteration, bind a click to the matching node, calling the anonymous function you provided

The problem here is that the function you provided is executed outside of your loop (e.g. when the click happens), so the value of `i` is whatever it was in the last iteration, in this case `2`

Comment: Nothing is "asynch" here...

Comment: Hah, fair. Perhaps "non-procedural" is a better choice of word

Comment: The callback registred in `click` can be seen as an async call...