# Can not check the radio button dynamically using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need one help. I need to check the radio button dynamically using Javascript/Jquery. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" id="answer_type0" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db13ed8cda709ffc8918">Scale
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" id="answer_type0" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736daffed8cda709ffc8917">Yes/No
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" id="answer_type0" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db29ed8cda709ffc8919">Written
</div>
<span>
  <button type="button" id="btn" name="btn" onclick="setRadioButtonValue()">Set</button>
</span>
```

Here 3 radio button are available .When user will click on set button one radio button should be checked as per given value. My javascript code is given below.

```
function setRadioButtonValue(){
  var valu="5736daffed8cda709ffc8917";
   $('#answer_type0').val(valu).prop('checked', true);
   console.log('check',document.getElementById('answer_type0').checked);
}
```

My updated code are available here

[updated plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/p54wZKQxLhjZF3b9uU3M?p=preview)

Here i need to check as per the given value(`i.e-var valu="5736daffed8cda709ffc8917"`) so as per code the `Yes/No` should be checked but in my case the first radio button always checked.Please help me to resolve this issue.similarly i need to also check the multiple set of radio button from each set. My [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/p54wZKQxLhjZF3b9uU3M?p=preview) code is here.

Comment: Why you are providing same id "answer_type0" for multiple radio buttons?

Comment: @MayankPandey : because i have get one value from them.

Comment: Where is the function `selectScale`?

Comment: its one function which will invove while it get checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case when the loop is complete i is always set to 2. If you want to do it with for loop see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750163/why-does-the-alert-coming-from-my-loop-always-return-the-last-value-not-each-it) or you can try this simple approach with adding a class within divs.

```
var valu = ['5736daffed8cda709ffc8917', '5736db13ed8cda709ffc8918', '5736db29ed8cda709ffc8919']

function setRadioButtonValue() {
    var i = 0;
    $('.qclass').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).find('input[value="' + valu[i] + '"]').is(':checked'));
        $(this).find('input[value="' + valu[i] + '"]').prop('checked', true);
        i++;
    })
}
```

Add a class for the div containing the radios in my case `qclass`

```js
var valu = ['5736daffed8cda709ffc8917', '5736db13ed8cda709ffc8918', '5736db29ed8cda709ffc8919']

function setRadioButtonValue() {
  var i = 0;
  $('.qclass').each(function() {
    
    $(this).find('input[value="' + valu[i] + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    console.log($(this).find('input[value="' + valu[i] + '"]').is(':checked'));
    i++;
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" class="qclass">
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db13ed8cda709ffc8918">Scale
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736daffed8cda709ffc8917">Yes/No
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db29ed8cda709ffc8919">Written
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" class="qclass">
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type1" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db13ed8cda709ffc8918">A
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type1" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736daffed8cda709ffc8917">B
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type1" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db29ed8cda709ffc8919">C

</div>
<br>
<br>
<div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" class="qclass">
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type2" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db13ed8cda709ffc8918">Male
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type2" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736daffed8cda709ffc8917">Female
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type2" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db29ed8cda709ffc8919">Male+Female

</div>
<span>
<button type="button" id="btn" name="btn" onclick="setRadioButtonValue()">Set</button>
</span>
```

Comment: let me to implement this.

Comment: its working but can i check whether each set radio button has checked or not in each iteration.`e.g-console.log(document.getElementsByName("answer_type"+i).checked)` like this to just print.

Comment: @subhra yes you can see the answer again. console.log($(this).find('input[value="' + valu[i] + '"]').is(':checked'));

Comment: Here its showing false i think because of adding before right ?

Comment: Yes it is. Try after the property change will show true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118539/discussion-between-subhra-and-prs).

Answer (score 1):

Use `attribute` selector and use `:radio` to select radio inputs.

Remove `duplicate-id` attributes

```js
function setRadioButtonValue(elem) {
  var value = "5736daffed8cda709ffc8917";
  $(elem).closest('div').find(':radio[value="' + value + '"]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db13ed8cda709ffc8918">Scale
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736daffed8cda709ffc8917">Yes/No
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db29ed8cda709ffc8919">Written
  <button type="button" name="btn" onclick="setRadioButtonValue(this)">Set</button>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type1" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db13ed8cda709ffc8918">Scale
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type1" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736daffed8cda709ffc8917">Yes/No
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type1" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db29ed8cda709ffc8919">Written
  <button type="button" name="btn" onclick="setRadioButtonValue(this)">Set</button>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type2" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db13ed8cda709ffc8918">Scale
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type2" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736daffed8cda709ffc8917">Yes/No
  <input type="radio" name="answer_type2" onclick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="5736db29ed8cda709ffc8919">Written
  <button type="button" name="btn" onclick="setRadioButtonValue(this)">Set</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Rayon : Here if i will not conside any id/name in case of multiple set of radio button what can be done.

Comment: Go with the classes instead of `id` and multiple `name` attributes can have same value...

Comment: Let me to explain again suppose for `name=answer_type0' there are 3 set of radio button and similarly for `name=answer_type1` another 3 set of radio button and i need to check each of them as per different value.

Comment: Please check my [updated plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/p54wZKQxLhjZF3b9uU3M?p=preview) code.Here i need to check one of each row using a loop.Can you please resolve it ?