# Creating a closure for .setTimeout() inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, frontend

I am trying to write a javascript program which stores the value from an input element in an array when a button is clicked. The array is the split and each individual letter added to a span element and then appended to the document. The idea is to create a typing effect using setTimeout.

I am running into an issue creating a closure within the loop, so currently the setTimeout function always returns the final value of the iteration.

The function in question is at the bottom of the code block and called addTextToBoard();

```
var noteButton = document.querySelector('[data-js="button"]');

noteButton.addEventListener("click",function() {
  var messageIn = document.querySelector('[data-js="input"]');
  var message = messageIn.value;
  postToBoard(message);
});

function postToBoard(val) {
  var noteBoard = document.querySelector('[data-js="noteboard"]');
  var newElement = document.createElement('div');
  newElement.classList.add('noteboard__item');
  noteBoard.appendChild(newElement);
  setTimeout(function(){
    newElement.classList.add('active');
  }, 200);
  addTextToBoard(newElement, val);
}

function addTextToBoard(el, val) {
   var wordArray = val.split('');
   for(i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
       var letter = document.createElement('span');
       letter.innerHTML = wordArray[i];
       setTimeout(function(x){
         return function() {}
         el.appendChild(letter);
       }(i),1000);
   }
}
```

I believe I am close, I'm just not fully understanding the syntax for creating the closure. If someone could give poke in the right direction, without necessarily giving the full solution that would be great.

I essentially tried to paste in the following code snippet from [here](http://brackets.clementng.me/post/24150213014/example-of-a-javascript-closure-settimeout-inside) but I've missed something somehwere along the way!

```
setTimeout(function(x) { return function() { console.log(x); }; }(i), 1000*i);
```

Best,

Jack

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266904/javascript-closure-not-working) helps you with fixing the closure

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

Since the "letter" variable changes, you'll add only the last letter over and over again. You need to "save" the current letter on the `setTimeout()` callback function, One way to go is like this:

```
function appendMyLetter(letter) {
  return(function() {
    el.append.Child(letter);
  });
}

function addTextToBoard(el, val) {
   var wordArray = val.split('');
   for(i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
       var letter = document.createElement('span');
       letter.innerHTML = wordArray[i];
       setTimeout(appendMyLetter(letter), 1000);
   }
}
```

This way, the `appendMyLetter()` function gets called with a different parameter (one for each letter) and returns a function with the correct "stored" value to be called by `setTimeout()`.

### EDIT

Looking at your `setTimeout()` code closely

```
setTimeout(function(x){
  return function() {}
    el.appendChild(letter);
}(i),1000);
```

It would work fine, if you used the proper parameters and used the `appendChild()` inside the returned function, like so:

```
setTimeout(function(x){
  return(function() {
    el.appendChild(x);
  });
}(letter),1000);
```

Comment: `return` in `setTimeout` doesn't make sense. Nowhere to return to

Comment: On my code, it calls and returns a function to `setTimeout`. That returned function will then be called after the given amount of milliseconds.

Comment: No... the anonymous function will. The IIFE is pointless inside it

Answer (score 0):

You can create an immediately-invoked function expression [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to create a closure

```
 function addTextToBoard(el, val) {
       var wordArray = val.split('');
       for(i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
          (function(index) {
            var letter = document.createElement('span');
             letter.innerHTML = wordArray[i];
            setTimeout(function(){
             el.appendChild(letter);
            },1000);
        })(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will work but here you go a slight change in operator:

```
letter.innerHTML += wordArray[i];
```

if you dont get the effect you imagined you will get you better try to increment the timer by i like this

```
setTimeout(function(){
 ...
},1000*i);
```