# Closure Inside For Loop

Tags: javascript, closures

I know that one of the ways to log 0 to 9 with this code:

**EDIT:** [Source](http://www.thatjsdude.com/interview/js2.html#closure)

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);
    }), 10)
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egbb88cx/)

is to make `setTimeout` self invoking and pass `i` as a parameter, like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout((function(i) {
      console.log(i);
    })(i), 10)
}
```

but I've tested making `setTImeout` self invoking without passing `i`, and it still works:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout((function() {
      console.log(i);
    })(), 10)
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egbb88cx/1/)

My questions:

1. Why does it work even without passing `i` as a parameter?
2. Is it necessary to pass `i`?

Comment: i doubt you are creating closure

Comment: You could equally have written `console.log(i); setTimeout(undefined, 10);`. So what? It doesn't work.

Comment: @user2181397 I've edited to clarify

Comment: @Bergi Not sure what  you mean?

Comment: Well, you have two scopes: the for loop, and the setTimeout. The loop has the variable i, so you don't need to pass i to the setTimeout; its already referenced.

Comment: @TheGenieOfTruth I added a link to the source. Do you mean the source is misinformed?

Comment: @JaeeunLee I mean that none of your two snippets actually creates a timeout or logs values asynchronously.

Comment: @Bergi They do work as intended. Added fiddles.

Comment: @JaeeunLee: Thanks for adding the source of the snippet. Unfortunately, it's wrong! Have a look at [our canonical question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572) for a better reference (and maybe also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266904/javascript-closure-not-working)).

Comment: Check this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/uqcterj3/)

Comment: @JaeeunLee: Add a `console.log("now")` after the end of the loop. You'd expect to see it before the logs from the timeouts, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Problem

It's not a Closure.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout((function(i) {
    console.log(i);
  })(i), 10)
}
```

setTimeout expects actually a function as parameter, but you made it invoking immediately. So it logs immediately the value of `i`, without waiting. setTimeout has now the return of your anonymous function as first parameter which is `undefined`.

The same here:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   setTimeout((function() {
     console.log(i);
   })(), 10)
}
```

It's executed immediately, it doesn't wait for the 10ms. The only difference you didn't passed `i` as parameter, but it will look in the parent scope for a variable called `i` – and there is one.

You will see that your anonymous function is called immediately if you set the time to e.g. one second (`1000`).

### Solution

A real closure would look like this:

Without parameter: You will see 10 times 10, because at time of execution of the inner function the loop is already finished which means i equals 10 at that time:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   (function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
         console.log(i);
      },10);
   })();
}
```

With parameter – you will get the expected result:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
         console.log(i);
      },10);
   })(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It would be great if you could also add how to make it work as it should.

Comment: Is the Solution #1 still a closure when it doesn't capture the value of `i` at the time of its creation? Or does it?

Comment: Actually the nature of a closure is to save the environment, save some variables and values like in the second example. So the definition of a closure is more than just an inner function. So if you're strict, I would say no, the first example isn't.

Comment: The first example is mostly used if you just want to create a new scope. Otherwise it doesn't make a difference if the setTimeout is inside of that function or directly in that for loop, the output is the same. They are called Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE).

Answer (score 3):

In all your avobe code, you are executing the function given as the first parameter in setTimeout without returning anything. So what happens is you are returning `undefined`.

In the code below, I am also self-invoking, but returning a function for setTimeout to execute after a specific interval`i * 10`.

This is the closure function. Check the console logs.It prints the time stamp in miliseconds. There is a gap of 10ms.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout((function(i) {
    return function() {
      console.log(i, performance.now() + 'ms');
    }
  })(i), i * 10)
}
```

***Additional Info***
In the comment section, I have a query

> what's the point, when you could just put the setTimeout inside an anonymous function?
>   So I guess this is the code you are suggesting.
>
> ```js
> for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
>     setTimeout(function() {
>       console.log(i, performance.now() + 'ms');
>     }, i * 10)
> }
> ```

If you run this snippet, you will get a log of 10 for every log. This is the beauty of closures. When you are executing the annonymous function

```
function() {
   console.log(i, performance.now() + 'ms');
}
```

It cant find `i` in current scope and searches it parent scope. And voila, it finds i, but unfortunately the loop has completed its iteration by that time and its value = 10 now. So logged 10 every time.

*This is why we need closure.*

Comment: Sure, but what's the point, when you could just put the `setTimeout` inside an anonymous function?

Comment: @torazaburo Buddy I have update my answer to accomodate your explaination. Please let me know if this is the thing you were refering or I am missing something.