# Do an array of on readystage function

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have an array of `XMLHttpRequest` (working fine) and I want to know when they are all finished. I wrote the following array of on readystatechange functions:

```
xhr[i].open('post', 'PHP/write_and_exec_opt.php');
display_opt[i] = xhr[i].onreadystatechange = function(index) {
    if (xhr[index].readyState == 4 && xhr[index].status == 200) {
        text = xhr[index].responseText.trim();
        n_finished++;
        console.log('display_opt', n_finished);
    }
    xhr[index].send(data);
}(i);
```

The xhr requests are executed properly. But no output on the console log. Why not?

Comment: It looks like you tried to use a [closure in the loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572)? Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25267864/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're **really close**, but by executing your anonymous function, you end up assigning its **return value** to the `onreadystatechange` property. You never return a value, so you assign `undefined`. You probably meant to return a function:

```
xhr[i].open('post', 'PHP/write_and_exec_opt.php');
display_opt[i] = xhr[i].onreadystatechange = function(index) {
    return function() {
        if (xhr[index].readyState == 4 && xhr[index].status == 200) {
            text = xhr[index].responseText.trim();
            n_finished++;
            console.log('display_opt', n_finished);
        }
    };
}(i);
xhr[i].send(data);
```

That said, it gets confusing fast and there's no good reason to create the temporary function repeatedly, which is why I usually break things out:

Somewhere *before* (or after, but in any case in the same fundamental scope) your `i` loop:

```
function createStateChangeHandler(index) {
    return function() {
        if (xhr[index].readyState == 4 && xhr[index].status == 200) {
            text = xhr[index].responseText.trim();
            n_finished++;
            console.log('display_opt', n_finished);
        }
    };
}
```

Then in your `i` loop:

```
xhr[i].open('post', 'PHP/write_and_exec_opt.php');
display_opt[i] = xhr[i].onreadystatechange = createStateChangeHandler(i);
xhr[i].send(data);
```

---

For what it's worth, I'd suggest looking into using promises for this sort of thing, esp. now that they're a standard part of JavaScript (as of ES2015):

```
Promise.all(xhrArray.map(function(xhr) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    resolve(xhr.responseText.trim());
                } else {
                    reject(/*...include some error perhaps...*/);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr[index].send(data);
    });
})
.then(function(array) {
    // `array` contains an array o the results, in the same
    // order as `xhrArray`
})
.catch(function() {
    // At least one XHR failed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 questions

1. no, there is no builtin method to catch when you array of `XMLHttpRequest` finished. you need implement it by yourself
2. you have no output because you don't assign function to `onreadystatechange`, you assign return value of execution of your function (`undefined` in your case).