# How to call an anonymous function from setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I have a loop, a setTimout and a callback. I need to use an anonymous function to keep the variables correct in the callback.

I want to have the callback as a separate function because it is too large to have in the loop.

This does not work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(callback, 1000*i, i);
}

var callback;
(callback = function(i) {
  console.log(i);
})();
```

How can define an anonymous function that I can call from setTimeout?

Comment: Just a heads up,  your 10 setTimeouts you have created will all execute in 1 second, and not over a period of 10 seconds.  Is that what your meaning to do?

Comment: Why have you wrapped the callback definition in an IIFE?

Comment: Just `function callback (i) { console.log(i) }` is enough for your case, since third parameter to `setTimeout` makes sure that `i` is correct.

Comment: http://brackets.clementng.me/post/24150213014/example-of-a-javascript-closure-settimeout-inside

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25267864/1048572

Comment: Just use `let i` and define the anonymous callback function inside the block scope of the loop

Comment: @Keith, you are correct, I was too quick, it should have been `callback, 1000*i, i)`, so it prints out one increasing number each second for ten seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you don't need anything more complex than this:

```js
function callback(i) {
  console.log(i);
};

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(callback, 1000*i, i);
}
```

You had two issues:

- You tried to use `callback` before you'd defined it.
- You wrapped your function in an IIFE (for no apparent reason), which means it would have been invoked once with an `undefined` argument.

Comment: Your immediately invoking the callback, you may as well not use the setTimeout in the first place.. :

Comment: yes, this is more then enough, since third param to `setTimeout` already takes care of it.

Comment: That it's :)   the parameter value.  I personally still prefer the closure route, just out of consistency for everything else were async is used.  New ES6 `let` solves all of this a lot simpler.

Comment: I missed a *i in the question, it should have been `setTimeout(callback, 1000*i, i)`...

Comment: Ok, I have probably misunderstood something. I was under the impression that `i` would be 9 by the time the callback is executed, and I, therefore, would need an anonymous function. Why is that not needed here?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my error. setTimout already handles this problem.

Comment: @EricC - `setTimeout` isn't doing anything special, it's just that you're not capturing any variables anywhere (because there are no closures), so the problem you're alluding to simply doesn't exist here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, it would seem to me that it's more logical to use `setInterval()` than `setTimeout()` in conjunction with a for-loop.

I've created a callback function using a closure to keep track of the counter variable in my example:

```js
function init() {
  var increment = initCounter();

  setInterval(function() {
    console.log(increment());
  }, 1000);
}


function initCounter() {
  var i = 0;
  return function() {
    return ++i;
  }
}

init();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the for-loop after the function expression.

This is following your approach.

```js
var callback;
(callback = function(i) {
  if (i !== undefined)
    console.log(i);
})();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(callback, 1000, i);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Better approach using function declaration:

```js
function callback(i) {
    console.log(i);
};

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(callback, 1000, i);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [ES6 Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
let callback = (i) => {
  console.log(i);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(callback, 1000, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing something, you're question is how to call an anonymous function, yet every single answer (including your own question) has included named functions.

What's wrong with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(m) { console.log(m); }, 1000*i, i);
}
```