# Javascript: how to avoid losing a variable when using a triggered function

Tags: javascript, html, variables, scope, eventtrigger

I am building several functions to be triggered when the user clicks over a link. The problem is that I use a loop to reduce code, but that loop uses a local variable. This variable is lost and appears (logically) as undefined when the user clicks the link -> executes the function.

I can't see any way to avoid that apart from explicitly using real numbers and no variables, but that makes the code really unsustainable. Am I missing some hidden options here?

```
for (var i=0; i<graphs.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<combinations.length; j++) {
        graph[i].label[j] = function() {return this.x + ' text ' + combinations[j].name;}
    }
}
```

This returns the logical 'combinations[j] is undefined' error. I can do the following

```
for (var i=0; i<graphs.length; i++) {
    graph[i].label[0] = function() {return this.x + ' text ' + combinations[0].name;}
    graph[i].label[1] = function() {return this.x + ' text ' + combinations[1].name;}
    graph[i].label[2] = function() {return this.x + ' text ' + combinations[2].name;}
    graph[i].label[3] = function() {return this.x + ' text ' + combinations[3].name;}
    graph[i].label[4] = function() {return this.x + ' text ' + combinations[4].name;}
}
```

And it works since all these variables are global (let's say they are accessible through a global variable) (except the previous loop-vars i and j)

Any idea?
Cheers

UPDATE:
As it turns out, I have solved it just by declaring another variable, maybe it works because it is created in every iteration? I ignore it, but it works as it should (perhaps because of how highcharts.js internally works)

```
for (var i=0; i<graphs.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<combinations.length; j++) {
        var workaround1 = i;
        var workaround2 = j;
        graph[i].label[j] = function() {return this.x + ' text ' + combinations[workaround2 ].name;}
    }
}
```

UPDATE2:
No, it doesn't help as the variable stores the last value and this is the one retrieved. The problem still persists.

UPDATE3:
Finally, and solved already here [How do I pass the value (not the reference) of a JS variable to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function), I have adapted the solution to mine

```
for (var i=0; i<graphs.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<combinations.length; j++) {
        (function(g) {
        graph[i].label[j] = function() {return this.x + ' text ' + combinations[j].name;}
        })(g);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using a function expression within a `for` block you have to pass in the iteration variable (`i` and `j` in this case). This tells the function expression the exact value without letting it be disposed

```
for (var i=0; i<graphs.length; i++) {
   for (var j=0; j<combinations.length; j++) {
      graph[i].label[j] = function(j) {return this.x + ' text ' + combinations[j].name;}
                                // ^ pass it into the function
   }
}
```

---

In response to comment: **Yes** you can do 2 variables. Here is a rough mockup

```js
var graph = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var combin = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

for (var i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < combin.length; j++) {
    (function(x, y) {
      console.log('[' + x.toString() + ',' + y.toString() + '] =' + graph[x] + combin[y]);
    })(i, j);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I pass 2 variables? If I do function(i,j) I can only retrieve "i", but not "j" ...

Comment: @Gerard. Short answer: Yes you can. I've updated my answer. You have to have the developer console open to view the results

Comment: Solved, now I get the meaning of the closures, updated in the original question

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work for me when passing j as argument

```
graph = [{"label":["foo","dsa"]},{"label":["foo","dsa"]},{"label":["foo","dsa"]},{"label":["foo","dsa"]}];
combinations = [{"name":"foo"},{"name":"bar"},{"name":"boo"},{"name":"far"}];


for (var i=0; i<graph.length; i++) {
for (var j=0; j<combinations.length; j++) {
    graph[i].label[j] = function(j) {return this.x + ' text ' + combinations[j].name;}
}}

console.dir(graph);
```