# Problem with adding integers in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop through my totals in order to get a grand total for my web app. So far the code I am working with is the following:

```
function calcAllFields() {
    var name = parseFloat($('div [name = total[]]').text());
    var totArray = $.makeArray(name);
    var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < totArray.length; i++) {
                total += totArray[i];
                }
    $("#target1").text(total);
}
```

Instead of adding integers, something is being read as a string. Say I want to add 200 + 50, instead of 250 I get 20050. Could anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You should really use JQuery for this its faster :)

Comment: @JonH, how exactly would more jQuery help here?

Comment: @Tatu it is an on going joke on the site about using JQuery, it's one of the first answers people come up with when there is an issue.  How would it help here - it wouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div[name=total[]]` probably contains multiple element's so that might cause some weird behaviour. Try this:

```
function calcAllFields() {
    var total = 0;
    $('div[name=total[]]').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).text());
    }
    $("#target1").text(total);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `parseInt` to ensure you're not concatenating a string.

E.g.:

```
total += parseInt(totArray[i], 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [cast to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript/2243631#2243631) using `+`, or `Number()`:

```
(+"200") + (+"50")              //-> 250
Number("200") + Number("50")    //-> 250

total += +totArray[i];
```

Personally, I prefer using `+` over parseInt/parseFloat in many situations because those functions will return a number as long as the string starts with a number, e.g. 1,000 would parse as 1.  +"1,000" will return NaN, which is more desired IMO.  You don't have to worry about the radix either, as +"010" will not be treated as an octal.

Comment: Another option I like to use sometimes is `|0`. In a case like this, a non-number would throw no error, it would default to `0`, so in effect, nothing is added if the input isn't a number.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, that can be useful in certain situations, too.

Comment: Careful with bitwise operations like `|`: they also clip the number to within the range of a 32-bit signed integer (potentially wrapping a large number into a negative number).

Comment: @bobince - thanks for the tip, you're right. I never knew that, but `'4294967297'|0` does return `1` as you warned.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried?

```
total+= parseInt(totArray[i]);
```

Comment: He also remembered the radix, so his code will work with `09` and such.

Comment: Also, to save you from future headaches, be sure to pass a `radix` a parameter to avoid unexpected results. For example, `parseInt('010')` will return `8`, but `parseInt('010', 10)` will return `10`, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you're getting as far as `20050`. The code shouldn't really work at all.

```
$('div [name = total[]]')
```

Firstly, that's not a valid selector. You would have to escape or quote the attribute selector, otherwise the first `]` in it closes the selector, leaving an invalid trailing second `]`.

It is only working at all because of a quirk (bug) in selector-parsing in jQuery/Sizzle. But because it's non-standard, (a) it might break in the future, and (b) it won't take advantage of the fast native `querySelectorAll` in modern browsers. Better:

```
$('div [name="total[]"]')
```

However you would need jQuery 1.4 for this because jQuery 1.3's attribute selector parsing was even more buggy and broke this case.

It might be better to avoid all these issues by just assigning a `class` to those elements and selecting on that instead.

```
$('div [name = total[]]').text()
```

What are the elements inside the `div` that have `name="total[]"`? I am supposing they are some sort of form controls otherwise the `name` attribute would be invalid. But `text()` is not the right way to read a form control. It gives you the textual content inside the element's tags, not the current value of the field.

`<input>`​s don't have textual content. `<textarea>` does have textual content, but it is not necessarily the same as the field's value. The textual content, like the `value` attribute of `<input>`, is the default-value of the field, not the current value. You should use `val()` to read the current value.

```
var totArray = $.makeArray(name);
```

That's no use. By calling `text()` on the selector wrapper object you have already thrown away the multiple elements you have in there to turn them into one text string. You can't get them back from a string. All `makeArray` does is give you an Array containing that single string as an item.

What you need to do is read the value of *each* input in turn, separately, in order to add them together.

```
var total= 0;
$('div [name="total[]"]').each(function() {
    total+= +$(this).val();
});
$("#target1").text(total);
```

(The `+` converts the value string into an integer, as per Andy's answer.)