# jquery: i have to use parseInt() even when deal with numbers, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following script

```
<select id="select1">
      <option value="1">1day</option>
      <option value="2">2day</option>
      <option value="3">3day</option>
    </select>

    <select id="select2">
      <option value="1">1day</option>
      <option value="2">2day</option>
      <option value="3">3day</option>
    </select>
```

and jquery

```
$("#select2").change(function() {
            var max_value = parseInt($("#select2 :selected").val());
            var min_value = parseInt($("#select1 :selected").val());
            if(max_value < min_value)
            {
              $("#select1").val($(this).val());
            }
        });
```

and now, what i can't understand anyway - if values of option elements are integer numbers, why i have to use parseInt()? in some cases it doesn't work without parseInt().

Thanks

Comment: Incidentally, you don't have to use `parseInt` here. [`+` will do as good a job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript/2243631#2243631), e.g. `var max_value = +$("#select2 :selected").val();`.

Comment: @Andy E's head - ...O_O. I never knew that trick! I can't decide if that looks prettier or uglier than an explicit conversion... but I'll probably go for it when I deal with a variable name or an object property rather than a method call.

Comment: @Matchu: it's one of my favourite things about JS, saving all those bytes ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form field values are always stored as strings. Whether or not they look like integers is irrelevant; they're strings. You need to convert them to integers before treating them as such :)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.uvsc.edu/disted/decourses/mct/2760/IN/krutscjo/lessons/06/ff_05.html

> Javascript treats most everything as a string unless you explicitly tell it that it is a number. One notable example of this is getting values from form elements. Depending on the browser and user input you may get some unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

Values are never integers as such, the fact that you put numbers there instead of who-knows-what is your choice only.

Comment: but when it compare two numbers, what is the problem?

Comment: Here is the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript/61545#61545

Comment: If you really want to know, watching "JavaScript: The Good Parts" will help you get the problem with not converting to the appropriate type before comparing as well as just about every common mistake there is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's val() function always returns a string. In many cases you can mix numbers and strings (in arithmic for example), when comparing two string variables, javascript will perform a string comparison, not a numeric comparison (which is to be expected)

Comment: ok, in this case,why the following is false?  if(14 > 12)..., even if it treats numbers as string?

Comment: @Syom: are you sure that the form values are what you think they are? My Google Chrome Javascript console says that `"14" > "12"` is true.

Comment: `(14 > 12)` will return true. `("14" > "12")` will also return true, but for different reasons.  OTOH, `("15" > "124")` will also return true

Comment: @Matchu: When you assert `String() > String()`, the assertion is alphanumeric order based, so `"a" < "b" == true`, `"11" < "12" == true`, but `"19" > "131" == true` (9 is further down the character list than 3).  This type of assertion with strings is commonly found in `array.sort()` functions.

Comment: @Andy E's head - Ahh. I had suspected something like that, but was too lazy to test it. Thanks :)

Comment: Then why do they write in the `.val()`'s docs that it "Returns: String or Number or Array"?