# Sort multidimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to sort an array containing arrays in ascending numerical order. The data structure looks like this

```
array = [[escalation],//integer
         [name],
         [email],
         [blackberry]];
```

I try to sort the array using this function (sorting by escalation)

```
function sortfcn(a,b){
 if(a[0]<b[0]){
    return -1;
 }
 else if(a[0]>b[0]){
    return 1;
 }
 else{
    return 0;
 }
}
```

But my output still looks incorrect...

0
0
10
12
14
16
18
20
20
8

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: What data type is *escalation*?

Comment: It should be an int, but apparently it was being read in as a string. Makes since, since I get it from the XML as .text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sort output you provided, it looks like JavaScript is reading the array elements as strings.  See if parseInt works:

```
function sortfcn(a,b){
 if(parseInt(a[0])<parseInt(b[0])){
    return -1;
 }
 else if(parseInt(a[0])>parseInt(b[0])){
    return 1;
 }
 else{
    return 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: You may want to add the radix parameter to parseInt as well: `parseInt(a[0], 10)` - this forces it to parse as base 10.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks!! I'll mark it as answer as soon as it lets me

Comment: Unary `+` is handy here too. e.g. `if (+a[0] < +b[0])`.  Neater than *parseInt*, IMO, and doesn't have the issue with the radix. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript/2243631#2243631