# Why are JavaScript negative numbers not always true or false?

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic, bitwise-operators

```
-1 == true;        // false
-1 == false        // false
-1 ? true : false; // true
```

Can anyone explain the above output? I know I could work round this by comparing to 0 but I'm interested. I'd expect at least one of the sloppy equals statements to be true as they do implicit type conversion, and I certainly didn't expect the ternary to come up with a totally different result.

Comment: @Select0r: how can -1 be === to a bool? they aren't even the same type

Comment: @Select0r well that would definitely return false in both cases. I guess the question is really about the way the sloppy equals works.

Comment: `how can -1 be === to a bool?` It can't, but using the type-safe comparison you'll don't have to worry about the `sloppy equals`.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In the first two cases, the boolean is cast to a number - [1 for *true* and 0 for *false*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript/2243631#2243631).  In the final case, it is a number that is cast to a boolean and any number except for 0 and NaN will cast to *true*.  So your test cases are really more like this:

```
-1 == 1; // false
-1 == 0; // false
true ? true : false; // true
```

The same would be true of any number that isn't 0 or 1.

For more detail, read the ECMAScript documentation.  From the [3rd edition [PDF]](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf), section *11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm*:

> *19*. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

It's worth giving the full algorithm a read because other types can cause worse gotchas.

Comment: One of dynamic typing's fuzzy lines.  If you know all the rules it all makes sense.

Comment: Fuzzy line indeed!  Use the `Boolean(-1)` for a true cast the way you expect - and discover -1 is still considered true (as in not 0).

Comment: These truthy/falsy values in JS (or any other dynamic language) values are just a hindrance more than they are useful; I always now fully compare in my conditionals.

Comment: If "any number except for 0 and NaN will cast to true" why does `2 == true` output false ? "2" is a number

Comment: @jackblank read again his first sentence. In your example, `true` is cast to `1`, not `2` is cast to `true` This [blog post](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/) is worth to read.

Answer (score 4):

In most systems, non-zero values are considered a true value, but that doesn't necessarily mean that they are the *same* true value as `true`. Thus, `-1 == true` doesn't necessarily hold, but `-1` can still be considered a true value since it is non-zero.

Really, though, you shouldn't be comparing integers to booleans if you can avoid it.

Comment: This isn't a particularly helpful answer, since it doesn't at all address the specific oddities of JavaScript type conversion/implicit truthiness.

Comment: I like this answer more than the accepted one, it explains the same thing in different one

Comment: JavaScript isn't "most languages", therefor not applicable.

Answer (score -3):

When evaluated as a test condition, integers like -1, 5 and 17,000,000, all return **Boolean true**, because they logically evaluate to true, e.g.

```
if(-1) {
    "This is true";
}
else {
    "This is false";
}
=> "This is true";
```

(Note: 0 logically evaluates to false)

Using the "?" operator does what this code just does. It passes the first argument as a condition in an *if* statement, passes the second argument as the **true** case, and passes the third argument as the **false** case.

Hence the third result.

However, these integers are not of the same *type* as **true**.

**True** is of type **Boolean**, **-1, 5 and 17,000,000** are of type **Integer**.

The comparison '==' is strict, in terms of type comparison. Even two things have the same "value", but not the same type, the "==" operator returns **false**:

```
if(6 == true) {
    "This is true";
}
else {
    "This is false";
}
=> "This is false";
```

Even the following will return false, because **"true"** is of type **String** and **true** is of type **Boolean**:

```
if("true" == true) {
    "This is true";
}
else {
    "This is false";
}
=> "This is false";
```

Hence, the first two results.

Note: If you'd like to compare values irregardless of type, use the "===" operator:

```
if(6 === true) {
    "This is true";
}
else {
    "This is false";
}
=> "This is true";
```

and also,

```
if("true" === true) {
    "This is true";
}
else {
    "This is false";
}
=> "This is true";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The explanations of == vs. === in this answer are incorrect. === is for strict type comparison, while == will attempt to auto-convert types.