# Having trouble finding a value in an array using $.inArray()

Tags: jquery, arrays, indexof

I have a value, and an array. I'm trying to see if the value is contained within the array. I'm using jQuery's 'inArray' method but the results keep telling me that it is not found.
What am I doing wrong?

here is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/p9xcb/

```
var array =  ["79C8A605-1384-4A51-8AC9-C53C1AE075D2", "E367CEEE-A344-4C63-B4B3-A1CC20D3DAF2", "1E3ED40E-935A-4895-960E-89FFD8CD81B9", "2E67F9E8-4770-497E-A938-0A145DA033AF", "35B33B09-6BD3-495E-9A3E-4B5D6DF8655E", "F419FB1F-4922-46B9-B651-8BB0D42510DD", "61FD263B-175E-4434-8A88-8E00418E2E14", null, "FF98229A-998C-49AD-9392-E4CE98115C0A", "C88B9D52-FE70-430C-B43D-D52F9B22E997", "1DDF2413-B453-42BB-8D78-7A7AAA94C353", "55D922B1-EBCD-4EC3-87A5-FA6AA38C9975", "0FA8079A-F76F-4CA5-B370-7B8B9AF2720A", "CF1971EF-E0C2-4C54-8131-A19FB14F2515", "A736854B-73A2-4282-85E0-6298D8AB815A", "DA280665-DC5E-4DF2-9FB1-924E1C8E4713", "9C73A934-9DDF-415C-A409-F2AC79493539", "FD950617-2C9C-4B6C-94F1-6C746699B636", "F184BBBE-C296-4F1D-9DD7-57F87D3B95A6", "676955FB-3F3D-4DC6-8F9D-A873A8440499", "5509E5C6-6650-4DF6-B7A9-49C8BC935B53", "7D88DCD6-431E-41EB-9A87-5C19C2D579FC", "509EA3D8-5B30-41F0-809B-D1E45BC30E3C", "6C4D6F4F-A188-4E6C-B40C-02AE4A5FFAAB", "710E2593-FE14-4CAB-B97C-95D96BB81266", "CBEB793E-A572-4995-8342-E9A48EF19E82", "A8C937F2-056C-46B4-8034-11CA4BB37A1D", "8E9B5E53-298B-4BDE-A696-20F102C28F12", "7BF7421C-CB21-4A44-BBA3-2CFD3A74C889", "F8D89224-7BB7-477F-BB8E-F5B2633A4111", "73F196CF-62F8-4F7A-9938-4F52404450E4", "B4D419D6-A5B8-4141-8C0E-ADCBEC72F2D8", "59ECF672-5C93-4E1E-8E30-6E0699874D61", "EC72A684-5888-48E1-99FD-FE455A50222F", "5D234D6D-E296-4D90-B87E-61FB6FB48702", "8EDD5718-E28A-4A4E-85BA-4DC9C072EAA8", "66FEA812-9945-4FFB-87CB-CCA828768FA0", "0025CB40-3016-4286-AD60-46685EDFD6A1", "508AC4D3-EA29-43A9-92CC-453FE2438D58", "030C5CBE-C227-4326-BED7-DB16A90D5A36", "2AAFF154-0FD0-4B60-9180-DE19A9E0890B", "64EBB0B4-81C1-46EB-8B1A-711A06E45FA3", "E1AA77B2-0E67-42A7-B7D7-A15D2A4EA448", "E9543440-E66E-4984-AC4E-091F161D33D6", "D93988D5-73D9-4988-B1A1-B48282F3C7B7", "6DC572B8-1F69-4A5C-81C7-6EAC617EBEE1", "BB56B36C-1D90-4B8D-ABF0-4ECD4052DCC1", "D1FEFB8D-84F4-4500-92F2-70FEE23F4B6E", "3A836ED4-639C-42C4-B945-375DC053FB61", "33672786-E964-4C3F-A3EB-7BF6634D13A0", "7F76C892-AEC1-4901-80BE-B93DFF59D159", "0E92F1AD-5C09-4B3D-BAF5-5D62BA3440EF", "73E50616-DCA7-4E83-B81F-100C21A18C49", "CF89704A-BD58-4D41-A5B5-10BAFC6F8085", "0D5CBF2A-3699-4968-A2DC-F6EA61D6C7C1", "FED50D50-86E8-42E2-8CD4-17DC01BB966C", "81EEFFA0-D172-4BC3-8474-2C55E6CB06CA", "8FA6CBBD-D5AC-431D-B1E3-C0D1BA48ECCA", "7EEA9381-F0F0-4252-BF29-D15A5A0283C6", "0FFDE30B-E4C3-40CC-A292-566D54D05821", "E24EE39E-0FDE-4C20-B61C-E5C07B483CF8", "82F6B86F-6EAB-42B4-B19D-CA6EAFF83A92", "7B663073-6296-4A08-89AF-7051EAFC3E8A", "EA36E8B5-A266-473C-A076-96A605A856B9", "4A99A5A0-FBF3-4AC6-A34A-52E761B98C8A", "26513617-D98B-44D9-BDD5-2FFCB8C7783B", "67F93D0F-E145-4447-A7B8-E3D1E944B88C", "9798FD1D-B781-4420-A37E-622E04E69672", "1A872624-E81B-45B7-B6FD-ED229AE54042", "092C0992-FAED-4E74-AB3E-6553F5261EF2", "76B94E6B-BE6B-43F2-ABBD-67A3B92C33B9", "AADF1B4D-F32E-4C0C-B4FC-EAC051338B8C", "E8A2479D-B1FC-4B67-AC94-C1AB8E1C7298", "8F7350C0-867D-461A-92D9-225CF8E91D60", "E742D55B-ADF0-4ADF-A3C9-EC4B3BAA832A", "320EBB4F-F0AB-47E7-A5B6-334429F8DEC8", "CEF5D66B-5EF2-468B-A9BE-06B0BC05E917", "CC6D2205-EB58-414D-A404-ED7B743E385E", "7D7EB4D0-BE31-4F28-928D-8E1FC5C947F0"];

var value = "CC6D2205-EB58-414D-A404-ED7B743E385E";

$('body').html($.inArray(value, array));​
```

Edit:

If I run this code

```
if ($.inArray(value, array)) {/*this will never be called, why?*/}
```

I will never see anything where `/*this will never be called, why?*/` section is.

Comment: It returns 77 in that fiddle.

Comment: Yeah I edited my question to reflect it not saying -1 any more

Comment: @DennisMartinez - What do you mean by "not found" then? It is found, at index 77.

Comment: if i call $.inArray() as like a check such as if ($.inArray(v, a)) {/*this will never be called, why?*/}

Comment: I get a 500 internal server error :)

Comment: @DennisMartinez you should add that as part of your question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first understand the concept of truthyness/falseyness in javascript. The following values will evaluate inside a boolean operator as false

```
undefined
null
empty string
false
0
```

And the following will evaluate true

```
non-null object reference
non-empty string
true
any non-zero number
```

Now do you see the problem using

```
if($.inArray(value,array)){

}
```

Hint: Not finding the element (-1) will evaluate true, finding the element in the first position (0) will evaluate false. Finding the value in any element after the 1st will evaluate true.

The easy fix is to use:

```
if ($.inArray(value, array) >= 0)
```

Comment: `Not finding the element (-1) will evaluate false` - this is not true.
`if(-1){true}` returns `true`.
`-1 == true` returns `false`.
See this question: [why-are-javascript-negative-numbers-not-always-true-or-false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619797/why-are-javascript-negative-numbers-not-always-true-or-false)

Answer (score 1):

> The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf()
>   method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the
>   first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.

In addition to that `inArray` returns the index of the occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

This *might* be your problem.  In javascript `if (0)` is going to be the same as `if (false)`, and `if (-1)` is the same as `if (true)`.  You need to use

```
if ($.inArray(value, array) >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
check = function (arr,val)
{
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
        try{
         if(arr[i].indexOf(val) != -1){
            return i;           
        }
        }catch(e){}
    }
    return -1;
}
```

use it like this `check(array,value);`