# Javascript, toggle a setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to make a small script where the screen will randomly change it's background color every 100ms, and you can toggle this on and off by pressing a single button. I can get it to start, but I can't get it to stop.

Here is the main code for toggling:

```
var on = -1;

function change() {
    on = on*-1;
    if (on == true) {
        var light = window.setInterval(disco,100);
    }
    else {
        window.clearInterval(light);
    }
}
```

`disco` is the function that changes the background color.

I've tried many different variations of this, but I think this is the closest I've gotten. Clicking the button now only set's another interval, despite the `on` variable correctly switching between 1 and -1. Am I not using clearInterval properly?

The full JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/VZdk9/

I'm trying to practice JavaScript, so no jQuery please :)

Comment: You'll need to place `var light;` outside of the function, else it will be "undefined" when its called a second time for the close action .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a scope issue with your variable `light` since it is defined inside the `change()` function. In order to keep track of the interval ID, you need to make it a global variable.

```
var light;

function change() {
    if (!light) {
        light = window.setInterval(disco,100);
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(light);
        light = null;
    }
}
```

I also removed your variable `on` since its possible values `-1` and `1` are both [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619797/why-are-javascript-negative-numbers-not-always-true-or-false). You really only need to use one variable since `light` will be reset to `null` if the interval has been cleared. If this variable is controlled by another function feel free to change it back.

Comment: 1 == true in javascript

Comment: Try evaluating this expression: !!(-1)

Comment: try -1 == true ))) !!(-1) is type conversion

Comment: In any case it's a bizarre way to handle a boolean value.

Comment: ok, i know but in question sample "on == true", and i just notise 1 == true, but -1 != true - so its ok

Comment: I was always under the impression that 0 and below could always be considered false, while 1 and above was always true. I guess that's not the case!

Answer (score 6):

```
var light = null;
function change () {
    if (light === null) {
        light = window.setInterval(disco, 100);
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(light);
        light = null;
    }
}
```