# variable set to minus number evaluates to true

Tags: javascript

This javascript console log is confusing me.
How can x which has the value of -1 be evaluated to true in the if statement where it false the line before it? Thanks

```js
x = -1
-1
x == true
false
if(x){console.log('yes')}
yes
```

Comment: Negative numbers (except zero) aren't falsey values.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3619813 `x == true;
// false` - the boolean is cast to a number in this case and thus the comparison becomes `-1 == 1 // false`

Comment: **Comparing** a value to a Boolean is *very* different from **converting** a value to a Boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you test `x` in your if statement, you're not checking if `x` is true, you're checking if `x` is truthey. The rules for truthiness in javascript are:

empty strings are falsey. all other strings are truthy.
`0` and `NaN` are falsey. all other numbers are truthy.
all objects and arrays are truthy.
`null` and `undefined` are falsey.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(-1){console.log('yes')}
```

prints 'yes' in console because **-1** and other numbers except **0** are **truthey** value, despite **-1** not equal to **true**.

[Here](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/) is a good source for extending knowledge related to javascript truthey and falsey values.