# running total using jQuery not adding numbers together

Tags: jquery, math

I'm trying to create a running total, unsuccessfully, what way would you do this:

```
var total = 0;
value = $('.price').text();
total += value;
$('#subtotal span').html(total);
```

All it does it add the next value to the "span" not actually add the figures together!

---

*EDIT: From content of answer posted by OP.*

```
$('.addtocart').click(function(){
                $('#cart').show();
                var omPartNo = $(this).next().text();
                var supPartNo = $(this).next().next().text();
                var cat = $(this).next().next().next().text();
                var desc = $(this).next().next().next().next().text();
                var manuf = $(this).next().next().next().next().next().text();
                var list = $(this).next().next().next().next().next().next().text();
                var disc = $(this).next().next().next().next().next().next().next().text();
                var priceEach = $(this).next().next().next().next().next().next().next().next().text();
                $('#cart table').append('<tr class="tableRow"><td><a class="removeItem" href="#"><img src="/admin/images/delete.png"></img></a><td>' + omPartNo + '</td><td>' + supPartNo + '</td><td>' + cat + '</td><td>' + desc + '</td><td>' + manuf + '</td><td>' + list + '</td><td>' + disc + '</td><td class="price">' + priceEach + '</td></tr>');
                    var total = 0;
                    value = parseInt($('.price').text(), 10);
                    total += value;
                    $('#subtotal span').html(total);
            });
```

This is my complete code. I think i'm doing this wrong, this isnt going to give me a running total is it??

Any help!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) here to loop through the elements, using [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) as you go (since they're prices), like this:

```
var total = 0;
$('.price').each(function() { total += parseFloat($.text([this]));
$('#subtotal span').html(total.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Number()` or `+` to explicitly cast to a number, which I prefer to `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` for several reasons:

```
value = +$('.price').text();
total += value;
$('#subtotal span').html(total);
```

Or, similar to @Nick's sample using each:

```
var total = 0;
$('.price').each(function() { total += +$.text([this]); });
$('#subtotal span').html(total.toFixed(2));
```

See also: [Hidden Features of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript/2243631#2243631)

Answer (score 0):

Your code only adds the text from the first element in the jQuery object `$('.price')`. If you're wanting this selector to add up all the elements that have class 'price'. then you should use the jQuery `.each` function to loop through the elements adding up the values.

It wouldn't hurt using the parseInt function during the addition as well.