# How to convert a string (with leading zero or not) to an integer?

Tags: javascript

How to convert a string (with leading zero or not) to an integer? For example, `'08'` to `8`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several ways to convert a string to a number, [I prefer to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript/2243631#2243631) the unary `+` operator:

```
var number = +"08"; // 8
```

This is the equivalent of writing:

```
var number = Number("08"); // 8
```

Unlike `parseInt()`, when using `+` or `Number()` no radix is necessary because the internal number conversion will not parse octal numbers.  If you want the `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` methods, it's also pretty simple:

```
var number = parseInt("08", 10); // 8
```

`parseInt` and `parseFloat` are less reliable for user input because an invalid numeric literal might be considered salvageable by these functions and return an unexpected result.  Consider the following:

```
parseInt("1,000");   // -> 1, not 1000
+"1,000";            // -> NaN, easier to detect when there's a problem
```

**Extra Reading**

- [Number() - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)
- [Converting to number (JavaScript Type-Conversion) - jibbering.com](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/#tcNumber)

Comment: what about 010 number not an string ?
parseInt(), Number, +, didn't work

Comment: @Umair: `010` is already a number.  In "loose mode" or older browsers, the number will be 8.  In strict mode, a syntax error will be thrown (but you can use `0o10` if you *transpile* with Babel or use newer browsers exclusively)

Comment: yes your are right it's already number i wanna get decimal value of this number or remove leading 0 how can  i do

Comment: @Umair: that seems really odd.  You can basically convert the number back into an octal string, then parse it correctly.  `+(010.toString(8))`, for instance.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with the `radix` argument. This disables autodetection of the base (leading 0 -> octal, leading 0x -> hex):

```
var number = parseInt('08', 10);
// number is now 8
```

Comment: the radix argument is the one i always forget sometimes. +1

Answer (score 3):

you can use `parseInt()`; with base 10 or `parseFloat();` to parse float

Answer (score 2):

Use the `parseInt` function. Reference: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp)