# jQuery - Features you couldn't live without

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I was conversing with a fellow coder last night and jQuery came up - he had never come across **jTemplates** or ever considered something like it may exist...

It got me thinking - *how many other incredibly useful features exist in jQuery that aren't being used because perfectly serviceable alternatives exist*?

I am hoping this question doesn't get closed - I'm aware it doesn't follow the modern Stack-Overflow QA paradigm, but I think it could form a useful resource and questions like this used to be common, so [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript) etc have similar offerings.

I'll start with the obvious:

- **Selectors** Need I say more?
- **Appearance Modifiers** - Various visual *effects* that can easily be applied to DOM elements. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/).
- **jQuery UI** particularly useful in conjunction with the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). Also many widgets and interactions. So far, I've only used the **Dialogue** and **Slider** controls, both performing excellently. [See here](http://jqueryui.com/).
- **.ajax** and it's variants (.get(), .load() etc.) - Takes all the pain out of making ajax requests. [See here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).
- **.live** Attach an event handler to all elements matching the selector now *and in the future*! Genius! [See here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).
- **jTemplates** - Alternative to the jQuery.tmpl() function, this plugin allows you to create powerful html templates for rendering data client-side. [See here.](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/)
- **qTip2** - Still officially in beta, but this plugin is simply the best for creating tooltips and much much more. [See here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/).
- **Deferred** - A clean and sensible way to manage asynchronous code. See [here](http://intridea.com/2011/2/8/fun-with-jquery-deferred?blog=company) for basic info and further links.

Please add anything I've missed, and I will update my list accordingly.

Comment: $.hide, $.show, $.animate, $.css - all the appearance modifiers.

Comment: Possibly related: [Hidden (or not widely known) features of jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121965/hidden-or-not-widely-known-features-of-jquery)

Comment: This seems more like a jQuery circlejerk than a proper, specific question.

Comment: @jensgram - I found that article, but it looked like it was aiming at identifying obscure jQuery functions, as opposed to this which is about the ones everyone SHOULD know about.

Comment: @BonyT Oh, you may be right. However, I guess you will run into trouble defining "should" :) I've never seen jTemplates before but have used `.tmpl()` to some extent.

Comment: I'm trying to create something like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c) for jquery.

Comment: @Delan and everyone who agrees with his comment - would you consider the C# and javascript topics cited above similarly? If not, then how is this post different??

Answer (score 2):

**Chaining**
Makes it beautiful (with room for making it a mess, though) and concise. Almost every jQuery method (including plugins) return a `jQuery` object for chaining unless a better alternative exists (e.g., the dimension methods etc.)

Answer (score 0):

ValidationEngine: Really awesome, easy validations!!

[Info](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)!