# Get price with in string with javascript using parseFloat an parseInt not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have retrieved a string and I extracted a decimal number from it using regex, e.g. 1.00 or 3.99. Now I wanna use these numbers for calculation. How can I convert those regex results into proper numbers so I can perform calculation? In the code below, every click should add the price to the previous total but it doesn't do the sum of numbers properly.

```
var SaveAfrica = {
  init: function () {
    this.addToBasket();
  },

  addToBasket: function () {
    var featured = $('section.featured'),
        bsktTotalSpan = $('.basket_total span.basket-qty'),
        list = featured.find('ul'),
        item = list.find('li');

    featured.delegate('.buy-now', 'click', function (e) {
        var thisElem = $(this), 
            qtyData = thisElem.closest('li').data('price'),
            total = parseInt(bsktTotalSpan.text()) + parseFloat(qtyData.match(/[\d\.\d]+/i));


        e.preventDefault();

        bsktTotalSpan.text(parseFloat(total));

        console.log('The total is: total);

    });
  }
};

SaveAfrica.init();
```

The HTML where the digit is from:

```
<li data-price="&pound;2.99"><a href="#" class="buy-now"><img src="someImage.jpg" alt="some image" /></a></li>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Not sure if it just got lost when you copied your HTML here, but your entity is missing a semicolon -- it should be `&pound;2.99`.

Comment: Thanks @josh3736, I'll fix this now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the sum come out to, if anything at all?

You may want to try the following instead:

```
total = parseFloat(bsktTotalSpan.text()) + parseFloat(qtyData.match(/[\d\.\d]+/i));
```

That is, parse **both of them to floats** And explicitly define total as a float. Otherwise, the decimals might be getting truncated somewhere.

Comment: @WillHall: In the sum, only the 1st digit before the comma, is updating, i.e. it updates as 2.99, then 3.99, 4.99 and so on, instead of 2.99, 5.98, 8.97 and so on... That's what I don't get...

Comment: Why is this better than simply multiplying the strings by 1? '1.5' * 1 = 1.5

Answer (score 3):

Your problem may be that `.match()` returns an array of matches. So you might try something like:

```
parseFloat(qtyData.match(/[\d\.\d]+/i)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo in while getting the price from the  element.

The code should be as below,

```
qtyData = thisElem.closest('li').data('data-price'),
```

Comment: I don't see any typo, where did you get that from?

Comment: the code above gets the price using the below code - 

qtyData = thisElem.closest('li').data('ps-price'),

but the price is stored in the attribute "data-price" inside the <li> element.

Comment: Oh, I see, it must have been when I tried to simplify the code for you guys, since it was more complex than that. I'll fix it now, thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can simply multiply the string by 1 in order to convert it into a number:

```
num = '1.00' * 1 //result is the number 1
```

Comment: People really should have to add comments when downvoting, especially since my solution works: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I wouldn't say that your "answer" is relevant to the question and would probably have been better off as a comment.  Nobody would expect a "different method of parsing floats" to work any better that `parseFloat` in this case.  As a side note, you don't need to multiply by 1, you can just write `num = +'1.00'`.  All mathematical operators coerce the operand to a number except when the operator is `+`, there are two operands and one of them is a string (in which case it becomes the concatenation operator). More info at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2243631.

Comment: @Andey E -- I don't understand you at all. The question was "How can I convert those regex results into proper numbers so I can perform calculation?" My answer provides a completely viable solution. So in what way is it not relevant to the question? Thanks for pointing out the even simpler option, btw.

Comment: well.. (didn't downvote either)... the user has a price with a pound in front of it (&pound;2.99), '&pound2.99'*1 is not going to give a result you can calculate with... So although you're right that you can convert '1' into 1 by multiplying it with 1, it's not what the user was looking for...