# About scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

When I change the first checkbox, I want to change the var `theSame`, but it seems it doesn't change in `if(theSame == 1);`
but it changes in `alert("b"+theSame)`. How to handle this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var theSame = 1;
            $("input[name='thesame']").change(function(){
                theSame = $(this).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
                alert("a"+theSame);
            });
            if(theSame == 1){
                $(".check_list input").change(function(){
                    alert("b"+theSame);
                });
            }
         });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="thesame">same
<br>
<div class="check_list">
    <input type="checkbox" name="son">ppp
    <input type="checkbox" name="son">ppp
    <input type="checkbox" name="son">ppp
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

thank you,this what i want to achieve:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name='thesame']").change(function(){
        var theSame = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
        show(theSame)
        });
       function show(i){
           if(i == 1){
            $(".check_list input").change(function(){
            var inputName = $(this).attr("name");
            $("input[name=" + inputName + "]").attr("checked",this.checked)
            });
       }else{
            $(".check_list input").unbind("change")
           }
        }
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="thesame" class="check-all">same
<br>
<div class="check_list">
    <input type="checkbox" name="son">ppp
    <input type="checkbox" name="sister">ppp
    <input type="checkbox" name="dog">ppp
</div>
<hr>
<div class="check_list">
    <input type="checkbox" name="son">ppp
    <input type="checkbox" name="sister">ppp
    <input type="checkbox" name="dog">ppp
</div>
<hr>
<div class="check_list">
    <input type="checkbox" name="son">ppp
    <input type="checkbox" name="sister">ppp
    <input type="checkbox" name="dog">ppp
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note — never use `$(this).is(":checked")`.  You can use `this.checked`, which is *much* faster performing *and* easier to read.  [A cool trick you can use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript/2243631#2243631) here is `+this.checked` instead of `this.checked ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? The code inside `if(theSame == 1){` will always run as you have just set `theSame` to 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a question of scope, but more of asynchrony.  Let's step through your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Define function-scope variable `theSame`, assign it a value of `1`
    var theSame = 1;

    // Bind a `change` event handler to an element, this function will run later!
    $("input[name='thesame']").change(function(){
        theSame = +this.checked;
        alert("a"+theSame);
    });

    // At this point, `theSame` has not changed from its original value!
    if(theSame == 1){
        $(".check_list input").change(function(){
            // Here, however, `theSame` may have had its value changed
            alert("b"+theSame);
        });
    }
});
```

So, as you can see, when the `if` statement runs it will always have a value of `1`, because the value isn't changed until later, after this code has already been executed.

If you move the `if` statement to inside the event handler, you'll see different results:

```
$(".check_list input").change(function(){
    if(theSame){
        alert("b"+theSame);
    }
});
```

Here, you'll only see the alert if `theSame` is `1`.

Comment: thanks for your answer!i have a try to move the if inside the event,but when i toggle click the first checkbox(in my project, it's a must does),then click other checkbox one time, it'll alert double times and more...

Comment: @user: It sounds like you copied the event binding along with the `if` statement into the `change` function, so every time it runs it binds the event again.  You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name='thesame']").change(function(){
        theSame = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
        alert("a"+theSame)
        show(theSame)
        });
       function show(i){
           if(i == 1){
            $(".check_list input").change(function(){
                alert("b"+i)
            });
       }else{
            $(".check_list input").unbind("change");
           }
        }
});