# Javascript VisualBasic's WITH equivalent?

Tags: javascript, set, field

Can't figure out how to set multiple object elements at a time?

For example, how to write

```
myobject.field1 = 12;
myobject.field2 = 13;
myobject.field3 = 14;
myobject.field4 = 15;
myobject.field5 = 16;    
myobject.field6 = 17;
```

without writing `myobject.` multiple times? Somehow with comma syntax?

Comment: Javascript has `with`. Look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript#61118

Comment: JavaScript also got `with` keyword. It's [not good practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement) to use it though.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript does have a `with`, but its use is [not recommended](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/), mainly because it can clobber variables outside of what `with` is supposed to work on (if the property does not exist).

You could turn those assignments into a loop...

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    myobject['field' + i] = 11 + i;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, just because I like to rant about `with` not being good practice and because I'd link the exact same post by Chuck No... ehem Doug Crockford.

Answer (score 1):

If your object only contains fields you can declare it like this:

```
var myobject = {
    field1: 12,
    field2: 13,
    field3: 14,
    field4: 15,
    field5: 16,
    field6: 17
};
```

If you use jQuery and your object has other functions and properties you can do this:

```
$.extend(myobject, {
    field1: 12,
    field2: 13,
    field3: 14,
    field4: 15,
    field5: 16,
    field6: 17
});
```

Comment: Those equal signs inside the { .. } should be colons and drop the last comma in each group.