# Please explain why and how +new Date(); works as 'workaround' for Date.now() in IE8 or below

Tags: javascript

(I'm reading the book "*Professional JavaScript for Web Developers*" to give a context about this question, specifically Chapter 5 on Reference Types)

I'm wondering why and how
`var start = +new Date();` works to get the current millisecond representation of now as a work-around to browsers (e.g.: IE8) that don't support ECMAScript 5's `Date.now()`?

What does the `+` operator do here compared to just plain old `new Date()` which also gets the current date and time?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What happens is that you first create a new Date object and then cast it to a number.

### TL;DR-version

Under the hood the runtime calls [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) method of the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

### Verbose-version

return a new [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object

```
var d = new Date;
```

use the [Unary + Operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.6)

```
var n = +d;
```

The unary + operator calls the internal [ToNumber](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) with `d`.

[9.3 ToNumber](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3)

Takes an *input* argument and if the *argument type* is `Object` (Date is) call the internal [ToPrimitive](http://es5.github.com/#x9.1) with *input* and **hint Number**.

[9.1 ToPrimitive](http://es5.github.com/#x9.1)

> takes an *input* argument and an optional argument *PreferredType*.

if *input type* is Object the spec says:

> Return a default value for the Object. The default value of an object
>   is retrieved by calling the [[[DefaultValue]]](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8) internal method of the
>   object, passing the optional hint *PreferredType*. The behaviour of the
>   [[[DefaultValue]]](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8) internal method is defined by this specification for
>   all native ECMAScript objects in 8.12.8.

[8.12.8 [[DefaultValue]] (hint)](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8)

> When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of O is called with hint
>   Number, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let valueOf be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "valueOf".
> 2. If IsCallable(valueOf) is true then,
>
>    1. Let val be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of valueOf, with O as the this value and an empty argument list.
>    2. If val is a primitive value, return val.

In code this approximately translates to:

```
var val,
    type,
    valueOf = O.Get( 'valueOf' );

if ( typeof valueOf === 'function' ) {
    val = valueOf.call( O );
    type = typeof val;
    if ( val == null || type === 'boolean' || type === 'number' || type === 'string' ) {
        return val;
    }
}
```

`[[Get]]`ting the internal method of O with argument "valueOf" basically means returning [Date.prototype.valueOf](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5.8).

[15.9.5.8 Date.prototype.valueOf ( )](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5.8)

> The `valueOf` function returns a Number, which is [this time value](http://es5.github.io/#this-time-value).

If we now go back to [9.3 ToNumber](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) we see that ToNumber calls itself, this time with the returned `val` from [8.12.8 [[DefaultValue]] (hint)](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8) as `primValue`. If *argument type* is Number it says:

> The result equals the input argument (no conversion).

***The End***

Comment: +1 for making the connection to `valueOf`, it's a reminder that you can mimic this behaviour [with *any* object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript/2243631#2243631).

Comment: so basically, `+` calls `valueOf()` of the object because it's trying to convert it to a Number?

Comment: "Secret valueOf()" achievement unlocked!

Comment: @Andy E: Great stuff at that link you shared =)

Answer (score 7):

**Date.now() function on IE:**

```
return a number of milliseconds between midnight, January 1, 1970, and the current date and time.
```

**Requirements**

```
Not supported in installed versions earlier than Internet Explorer 9. However, it is supported in the following document modes: Quirks, Internet Explorer 6 standards, Internet Explorer 7 standards, Internet Explorer 8 standards, Internet Explorer 9 standards, Internet Explorer 10 standards. Also supported in Windows Store apps.
```

**For get current Date object on IE8, you can use this:**

```
if (typeof Date.now !== 'function') {
  Date.now = function () { 
      return new Date(); 
  }
}
```

**For get time value in a Date Object** (as the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970.) **on IE8, you can use this:**

```
var currentDateTime = +new Date();
```

Comment: This answer would actually cause problems in IE8 and prior, as `Date.now` would be undefined, so trying to invoke it as `Date.now()` would result in an error. However, it'd be very easy to do something like:

```if (typeof Date.now === 'undefined') {
        Date.now = function () { return +new Date(); }
    }```

Comment: Echoing @BrianArnoldSinclair - invoking `Date.now()` in the `typeof` check cause the error. I tried to edit the post to correct it to `typeof Date.now` such that I check the function and not the result - but SO didn't allow for edits less than 6char long

Answer (score 6):

The unary `+` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29) converts a value to a number. For example `+"123"` will convert the string `"123"` to the number `123`. This will also work for a date, and the date converted to a number gives the number of milliseconds.