# How can I get seconds since epoch in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

On Unix, I can run `date '+%s'` to get the amount of seconds since epoch. But I need to query that in a browser front-end, not back-end.

Is there a way to find out seconds since Epoch in JavaScript?

Answer (score 320, accepted):

```
var seconds = new Date() / 1000;
```

Or, for a less hacky version:

```
var d = new Date();
var seconds = d.getTime() / 1000;
```

Don't forget to `Math.floor()` or `Math.round()` to round to nearest whole number or you might get a very odd decimal that you don't want:

```
var d = new Date();
var seconds = Math.round(d.getTime() / 1000);
```

Comment: `var seconds = new Date() / 1000;` <-- what kind of arcane magic is this?

Comment: Re: arcane magic:

Per [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Using_Number_to_convert_a_Date_object), Javascript knows how to convert a Date object to a Number.

This means that you can type `Number(new Date())` to get a number, or even `+(new Date())`, or use any Date instance in a numerical context such as `new Date()/1000` and Javascript will helpfully convert that Date instance to a number to work with your math equations.

Comment: TypeScript won't accept `new Date() / 1000;` but `new Date().getTime() / 1000
` works just well

Answer (score 68):

Try this:

```
new Date().getTime() / 1000
```

You might want to use `Math.floor()` or `Math.round()` to cut milliseconds fraction.

Answer (score 45):

You wanted seconds since epoch

```
function seconds_since_epoch(){ return Math.floor( Date.now() / 1000 ) }
```

example use

```
foo = seconds_since_epoch();
```

Comment: This should be the answer as it takes into account the decimal.

Answer (score 15):

The above solutions use instance properties. Another way is to use the class property [`Date.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now):

```
var time_in_millis = Date.now();
var time_in_seconds = time_in_millis / 1000;
```

If you want time_in_seconds to be an integer you have 2 options:

**a. If you want to be consistent with C style truncation:**

```
time_in_seconds_int = time_in_seconds >= 0 ?
                      Math.floor(time_in_seconds) : Math.ceil(time_in_seconds);
```

**b. If you want to just have the mathematical definition of integer division to hold, just take the floor. (Python's integer division does this).**

```
time_in_seconds_int = Math.floor(time_in_seconds);
```

Comment: Are you concerned that possibly the computer is running javascript prior to 1970?

Answer (score 11):

If you want **only seconds** as a whole number without the decimals representing milliseconds still attached, use this:

```
var seconds = Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a Date object (which will have the current time in it) and then call `getTime()` to get the ms since epoch.

```
var ms = new Date().getTime();
```

If you want seconds, then divide it by 1000:

```
var sec = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
```

Answer (score 4):

My preferred way:

```
var msEpoch = (+new Date());
var sEpoch = (+new Date()) / 1000;
```

For more information on the `+` [jump down the rabbit hole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430357/please-explain-why-and-how-new-date-works-as-workaround-for-date-now-in).

Answer (score 2):

The most simple version:

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

EPOCH means time from 01 January 1970

```
var date = new Date();
```

Following line will return the number of milliseconds from 01 Jaunary 1970

```
var ms = date.getTime();
```

Following line will convert milliseconds to seconds

```
var seconds = Math.floor(ms/1000);
console.log("Seconds since epoch =", seconds);
```

Answer (score -1):

In chrome you can open the console with F12 and test the following code:

```
var date = new Date().getTime()
console.debug('date: ' + date);

if (Date.now() < date)
    console.debug('ko');
else
    console.debug('ok');
```

https://www.eovao.com/en/a/javascript%20date/1/how-to-obtain-current-date-in-milliseconds-by-javascript-(epoch)