# How to declare a variable which is equal to 30 seconds in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a timer for 30 seconds and i'm looking to do this on my own, however I seem to be stuck here:

```html
var Starttime = ( needs to be 30 seconds )
var Timeleft = Starttime - 1

if (Timeleft === 0) {
  console.log("TIMER FINISHED BEEP BOOP");
}
```

and through lots of research still not able to find how to declare variable as a simple 30 seconds of time, and I am aware that I would need to do the same for the 1 ( change it to 1 second). TL;DR how do I write 30 seconds

Comment: If you are trying to code a timer you can store the seconds directly as normal numbers and use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to update it and check when it is finished

Comment: How to get current time in seconds (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456138/how-can-i-get-seconds-since-epoch-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this function using [setinterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) :

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
//this is where you can modifies the time amount.
    var minutes= 60 ,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(minutes, display);
};
```

```html
<body>
    <div>One minute countdown <span id="time">1:00</span> minutes!</div>
</body>
```