# Format date variable

Tags: javascript, date, time, jqplot

I have probably very simple question. I downloaded the http://jqplot.com javascript library and it provides the following example:

```
loc.push([[1340877779000, 2, 'start'] , [1340877869000, 2, 'end' ]]);
```

I need to substitute 1340877779000 with my variables that specify the time. I have:

```
var date_start = "2012-08-12 11:15";
var date_end = "2012-08-12 12:00";
```

How can I format 'date_start' and 'date_end' variables in order to use them inside loc.push()?

Comment: It's jqplot - www.jqplot.com/docs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try:

```
var date_start =  +new Date('2012-08-12 11:15');
```

**Update**

However it doesn't seem to work in firefox and IE. For firefox this should work (webkit can also consume it):

```
+new Date('2012-08-12 11:15'.replace(/-/g, '/'));
```

I'm not sure about IE, don't have any to test.

Comment: What is the `+` on the `new` do?

Comment: The same as `new Date('2012-08-12 11:15').getTime()`. This is type casting so the results converts to integer.

Comment: Do you know of any documentation on that? I've never encountered that before, would like to read about it.

Comment: This has same problem as `Date.parse` Does not work in firefox or ie. @JaredFarrish Docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf

Comment: @Esailija - Where does that explain the `+`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430357/please-explain-why-and-how-new-date-works-as-workaround-for-date-now-in

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, `+{valueOf: function(){alert("hello"); }}`. Trying to convert an object to a number triggers its `.valueOf` method.

Comment: @Esailija - So it's the [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish the operator isn't relevant. You could use `1* new Date` or `new Date - 0` or so on. All trigger the conversion to a number.

Comment: @dfsq: Nice! I didn't know that! Very usefull.

Comment: This answer is still very wrong :) The result is `NaN` in firefox and IE.

Comment: One strange thing that you will get `NaN` only if the `hour:minute` is specified. Without it, the parse works correctly. With the `replace` it works properly in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, how to place the variables inside the array?

```
loc.push([[date_start, 2, 'start'] , [date_end, 2, 'end' ]]);
```

Comment: He wants to convert his dates to milliseconds.

Comment: yep. how can I quickly convert these dates to miliseconds without writing my own function? is there any built-in javascript function?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date.parse`

```
Date.parse("2012-08-12 11:15")
// returns 1344784500000
```

So it would follow that you should use

```
var date_start = Date.parse("2012-08-12 11:15");
var date_end = Date.parse("2012-08-12 12:00");
loc.push([[date_start, 2, 'start'] , [date_end, 2, 'end' ]]);
```

Comment: Do I need to include any library to use Date.parse? Now alert(date_start) returns NaN.

Comment: `Date` is built-in. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp    If you are getting NaN, you might have some format error in the date string

Comment: I don't think `Date.parse` is available in all browsers, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var date_start = new Date("2012-08-12 11:15").getTime();
var date_end = new Date("2012-08-12 12:00").getTime();
loc.push([[date_start, 2, 'start'] , [date_end, 2, 'end' ]]);
```