# Invalid state Error in Firefox for Indexed Db

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I am getting an error when opening an indexedDB database on Firefox. This code works fine in Chrome, but fails in Firefox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
  var request = indexedDB.open("TestDB", 1);  
</script>
```

The Javascript error occurs on the line `indexedDB.open("TestDB", 1)`.

Comment: What browser does this fail in? Works fine in Chrome/Aurora

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/IDBEnvironment for a good way to check for browser-specific support.

Comment: I tried the example suggested in this link http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/
It is also not working for me

Comment: have to try restarting FF or clear data? Also try with my library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db Just try `db = new ydn.db.Storage("TestDB"); db.count('store name').done(function(x) {console.log(x);});`

Comment: did you allow the use of indexeddb when you went the first time to the page?

Comment: Same error here on FF 19.0.2; the code works on Chrome but fails on Firefox. The script above reproduces the error.

Comment: I think it may have to do with history settings in FF.

Comment: it does NOT reproduces the error in FF.

Comment: What is the error you get on that rule? More information about the error could explain more...

Comment: @KristofDegrave see my answer below, which also explains problems with reproducibility.

Comment: Ok, this means it is solved?

Answer (score 10):

In my case, this error was due to privacy settings in Firefox. Setting history settings to "Firefox will: Remember history" in the preferences panel enabled IndexedDB to work.

Comment: Your solution is more agreeable. Have a look at the limitations section in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB

Answer (score -2):

indexedDB object is method of window instance, so it must be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB ||  window.msIndexedDB;
var request = indexedDB.open("TestDB", 1);  
</script>
```

In you code, indexedDB become a local function. It doesn't work, obviously.

Comment: You made it worse. And why would a local function not work? [Functions are first class citizens in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/61094/383793)

Comment: these API functions (another one is indexedDB.cmp) should bind the owner object instance when invoking them. They are not pure function, although they should be since we are not using any instance variables (from user point of view). But from browser point of view, these function are not pure due to security check, they need to assess owner instance object.