# How do i compare against an empty variable?

Tags: javascript, is-empty, appconkit

If I set a variable to 0, I get the weird behavior that a comparison to "" (empty) is true. How do I check that the variable is really empty?

```
tmp = 0;

if ( tmp != "")
{
    //do something - This is where the code goes.
}
else
{
   //isEmpty - I would expect to be here
}
```

Comment: try

`if(!tmp)`

or maybe
`if ( tmp !== "")`

that should work

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript

Comment: Try `tmp!==undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [strict comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)
`===` and `!==`

With `==` and `!=` (called abstract comparison operators),

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript attempts to
>   convert the operands to an appropriate type for the comparison.

---

If by empty, you want to check if the variable hasn't been defined, use:

```
if (typeof tmp !== "undefined") {
    // it exists!
}
```

Comment: Well I'm not sure whether "undefined" is what I was looking for, but the strict comparison was new to me. Now the code goes where I expected it to go. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `empty variable`? If you mean an empty string, then you should use `!==` to check it.

```
if (tmp !== "")
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript implicitly converts values to other types. To check type also, use the `!==` operator:

```
if ( tmp !== "")
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript everything except `0`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `false` and `null` are considered to be false. "" is considered as `true`.

```
if (tmp) {

}
```

Above `if` will be executed if variable contains any value other than `0`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `false` and `null`.

If `tmp` is a `string` then you can use the following code:

```
if (tmp !== "") {

}
```

`===` and `!==` operators compare without doing type-conversion.