# When are parentheses and new keywords required when creating new objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, object

I'm studying objects in JavaScript and confused when the `new` keyword and `()` are required when using a object creation expression.

```
var a = new Date();     // current date and time
var b = Date();         // current date and time
var c = new Date;       // current date and time 
var d = Date;           // => function Date() { [native code] }
```

Is there any difference in the first three methods? Why doesn't `d` do as expected?

Comment: `new Date == new Date()` but `Date != Date()`.

Comment: Related, but not quite a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given: `new Date()`

This is the "standard" way to create a new object from a [constructor-function](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.4)<sup>1</sup>; it returns a new Date object representing the current time.

Given: `Date()`

JavaScript [defines the Date function to operate like this](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.2) when not called as a constructor (ie. with `new`). It returns a *different* value - a string and *not* a Date object -  than `new Date()`. See [Why we can't call methods of Date() class without new operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544001/why-we-cant-call-methods-of-date-class-without-new-operator).

User-code can also check the value of `this` inside a constructor-function to determine if `new` was used, although this is only done relatively infrequently. See [How to detect if a function is called as constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367768/how-to-detect-if-a-function-is-called-as-constructor)

Given: `new Date`

*When using `new`* the parenthesis are optional if there are no arguments. This is just an additional syntax form that most people don't use - it is *equivalent* to `new Date()` if the expression is terminated. See [Can we omit parentheses when creating an object using the "new" operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject)

Given: `Date`

This evaluates the expression to the constructor-function (which is just a function-object!<sup>2</sup>) *without* invoking it or creating a new instance. This is why the result shows a "function" - it is *the* constructor-function.

---

<sup>1</sup> I use the term constructor-function to emphasis the point that a constructor is *only* a function that [also] supports `new`; it is technically sufficient to call it a constructor.

<sup>2</sup> Likewise, it is important to understand that function[-objects]s in JavaScript are first-class citizens and thus just values themselves; like any object. In the last example the assignment of the object/value occurred without performing any action (ie. [function invocation](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.3)) upon the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` is a constructor function:

```
function Date() {}
```

When you use `new` you create an instance of `Date`:

```
var date = new Date;
date instanceof Date === true
```

The parenthesis are optional if you don't pass any arguments.

Now, `Date` on its own, is a reference to that constructor function. Therefore the line below:

```
var date = Date
```

Is simply assigning that function to a variable called `date`. While this other line:

```
var date = Date()
```

Is invoking the constructor function. But, without `new` it doesn't necesasarily mean it will return an instance of `Date`. This behavior is up to the function to decide; many constructor functions in JavaScript can be called without `new`. The function might handle it like this:

```
function Date() {
  if (!(this instanceof Date)) {
    return new Date()
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date` is a reference to a function. Simply referencing it doesn't execute it. That's why `d` acts that way.

`new Date` and `new Date()` both return a new instance of the `Date` object. One just doesn't have the option of passing in arguments.

I think `Date()` does the same, but this is not standard behavior for constructors. Functions will sometimes return new instances of objects.

`function Fun(){
  return new Trick();
}`