# What is the difference between Date(d.getTime()) and new Date(d.getTime()) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have been working with dates and realized these 2 commands `Date(d.getTime())` and `new Date(d.getTime())` are different.

When I run this snippet:

```js
        var d = new Date(2016,11,12);
        console.log(Date(d.getTime()));
        console.log(new Date(d.getTime()));
```

I have this result:

```
﻿(index):68 Thu Dec 12 2019 18:02:41 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
(index):69 Mon Dec 12 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão de Brasília)
```

Why are they different?

I have tried to find some answers but I find none. These are some of references I have gone through:

[Difference between Date(dateString) and new Date(dateString)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505693/difference-between-datedatestring-and-new-datedatestring)

[Why we can't call methods of Date() class without new operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544001/why-we-cant-call-methods-of-date-class-without-new-operator)

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.2

Comment: How does that first link in your question not directly answer your question?  This looks like it should be closed as a duplicate of that question....  How is the second question not *also* a duplicate?

Comment: I understand one is a function that works different from an object method. But why weekday is different?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* they be different? What is unclear?

Comment: Not completly, still have the weekday issue.

Comment: Why Dec 12 is Mon and Thu at same time?

Comment: Because 2019 and 2016 are different years?

Comment: because one is 2016 and the other 2019 ...

Comment: lol, now i get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Date(x)` returns a string representing the ***current*** time, the arguments are ignored.
  See [date constructor called as a function](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.2) in the specs. This is the expected behavior.
- `new Date(x)` returns a `Date` object initialized with x.
  See [one-argument variant of the date constructor](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2).

Comment: Ok, but why are they different weekdays?

Comment: @DiogoBratti read the part that says "representing the current date irrespective of the argument passed to it".

Comment: Ok, but why Dec 12 is Mon and Thu at same time?

Comment: @DiogoBratti do you think Dec 12 is the same day every year?

Comment: @DiogoBratti It's not?  2016 is not 2019.

Answer (score 2):

`Date` gets the `window`/global `Date` object, `new Date()` creates a new static `Date` object. When you create a `new Date()` you are freezing its value in time.

When you use `Date()`, it returns a string representation of the current date as if calling `new Date().toString()`.

Based on your code:

```
// this is a new date, Dec. 12, 2016
var d = new Date(2016,11,12);  

// this returns the time value of Date d
d.getTime()

// Calling Date as a function just returns a string for
// the current date, arguments are ignored
console.log(Date(d.getTime())); 

// this creates a new date based on d's time value
console.log(new Date(d.getTime()));
```