# Variables not treated as numbers

Tags: javascript, variables

I was explaining some basic javascript stuff to someone and found myself very embarrassed when a variable was not treated as a number, albeit being a number.

There are no NaN checks here, but we only input numbers.

```js
var number1 = prompt("choose any number");
var number2 = prompt("choose another number");
alert("thank you I will multiply your numbers now!");
var multiplication = function(a, b) {
    var c = a * b;
    alert("the product of " + number1 + " and " + number2 + " is: " + c);
    var number3 = prompt("please choose a number to add to the product.");
    var sum = c + number3;
    alert(sum);
};

multiplication(number1, number2);
```

It seems that variable "number3" is not treated as a number and the last alert does not give a sum but rather treats "number3" as a string.

Things get better when I use trivial

```
var sum = c + +number3;
```

I cannot understand why number3 is not treated as a number, any ideas? I could not explain this to my friend and had to retreat in disgrace.

Tired on Chrome and Firefox with the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

[`Window.prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt) always returns a String, event if it's numeric like "5". Still string. You need to perform casting from string type to number. For example using `Number` constructor:

```
var number1 = Number(prompt("choose any number"));
var number2 = Number(prompt("choose another number"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`prompt()` returns a string, simple as that. The `*` operator apparently casts the first two cases into numbers, but `+` is also the concatenation operator. So what happens is that now you have `number + string = string`. When you do `+number3`, that (the unary `+`) casts to a number. So now you have `number + number = number`, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanx, this is most excellent explanation! Did not know that prompt was doing this and that * somehow overrides this.

Answer (score 1):

The [`prompt` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt) always returns a string, it doesn't try to convert the text that you entered into a number even if it looks like it could be a number.

When you use the multiplication operator on two strings, both will implicitly be converted to numbers, because the multiplication operator only accepts numbers.

When you use the `+` operator on a number (`c`) and a string (`number3`), it will do string concatenation, not addition, because at least one of the operands is a string. It will convert the number to a string and concatenate it to the other string.

Using the unary `+` operator on the `number3` variable will implicitly convert the string into a number, because the unary plus operation can only be done on a number. It's clearer to use a function that explicitly converts the string to a number than using implicit conversion:

```js
var number1 = parseFloat(prompt("choose any number"));
var number2 = parseFloat(prompt("choose another number"));
alert("thank you I will multiply your numbers now!");
multiplication(number1, number2);

function multiplication(a, b) {
  var c = a * b;
  alert("the product of " + number1 + " and " + number2 + " is: " + c);
  var number3 = parseFloat(prompt("please choose a number to add to the product."));
  var sum = c + number3;
  alert(sum);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is overloaded as a *[arithmetic addition operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)* and as a *string concatenation operator*.

For the majority of cases, a value added to a string results in a string.  Because `prompt()` returns a string, that is what's happening.  You can use the unary `+` to turn the string back into a number (`+number3`), thus removing all the strings from the equation.

Note: Order of Operation does Matter

```
4 + 5 + '1' + 1     // '911'
```

The 4 and 5 are operated on first (both not strings) so arithmetic addition is executed.  Then the first '1' is encountered, which is a string, so a string is involved going forward and every `+` will be a string concatenation.

Comment: The OP already tried that and saw that it worked, he wanted to know what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

As everybody explained you are working with`strings` returning by the prompt.

And just for the sake of fun/quirks things that `javascript` have. look how you can turn that strings in  numbers

multiplying by number 1 will automatically turn all the string in numbers. so in the prompt side you could you multiply the result of `prompt1 and prom2 * 1` and you will not have that problem

also you can do `"1" * 1` -> **1 integer**

more interesting hide javascript features [Hidden Features of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript)

Comment: *"if you have "1" * "2" * 1 multiplying by number 1 will automatically turn all the string in numbers."* - The multiplication between the strings will implicitly convert both to numbers, multiplying by a number doesn't make any difference.

Comment: well what about "1" + "11" = `111` "1" + "11" * 1 = `12`

Comment: I edited my question a little bit and you were right whit that specific exmaple...

Comment: The expression `"1" + "11" * 1` doesn't evaluate to `12` but `111`; eventhough the multiplication turns `"11"` to `11`, the first operand is still a string so the `11` will be turned back to a string.

Comment: `"11"*1 + "1"*1` >> 12 now

Answer (score 0):

The [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1) helps explain how automatic type conversion is working here. [`+`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6) performs string concatenation if one of the operands is a string, while [`*`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5) only performs numeric multiplication, and so converts the operands to numbers.