# How does Date's constructor overload the unary +?

Tags: javascript, operator-overloading

I was reading [this answer to Hidden Features of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2243631/4532996) and was perplexed by this behaviour:

```
> new Date
< Fri Feb 26 2016 21:15:43 GMT-0500 (EST)
> +new Date
< 1456539382581
< 0 + new Date + 0
"0Fri Feb 26 2016 21:17:39 GMT-0500 (EST)0"
```

So, the `Date` constructor returns an object which, when converted to a number via unary (but not via addition) returns a number representing the Unix Epoch.

How is this possible? Reading about the topic, it seems like JS has no support for operator overloading, or only a small amount if overloading non-operator functions (`add`, `toString`, whatever) counts.

JS doesn't seem to have any such function for unary + specifically (or number coersion at all, it seems), so how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unary operator + converts its operand to a number if it isn't already.

So `+new Date` is similar to `Number(new Date)`.

```
new Date() // Fri Feb 26 2016 21:45:32 GMT-0500 (EST)

Number(new Date()) // 1456541132899

+new Date() // 1456541132899
```

Update:

**What's special about the Date object that makes calling Number on it return the Unix time?**

Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC (From MDN). So, it makes sense when we ask it to convert it to a number, it returns us milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

### Automatic type conversion of Dates.

The primitive numeric value of a Date object, returned by [`Date.prototype.getValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) is a Unix time stamp, the number of milliseconds since  1 January, 1970 UTC and is the value of a Date object converted to a number.

When converting an object to number following a unary + operator, the javascript engine explicitly asks the object to return a number, by calling the objects internal `toPrimitive` method with a hint value of "number" as described in  section [7.1.1 of the ES6 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive). This mechanism converts Date objects to milliseconds after a unary + sign in fairly standard fashion.

So how to explain how Date objects become converted to a *string*  when used as the operand of a *non unary plus*?. It would seem that for the non-unary case, type conversion requests an object's primitive value *without supplying a result type hint* and . . . Date provides an exotic [`toPrimitive` function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype-@@toprimitive) which converts dates to `string` by default instead of to `number`. Date and Symbol are special in this regard and differ from most other objects.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a little description about unary plus from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus):

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already.

If the operator cannot parse a string/value, it returns `NaN`.

Comment: ...and? Read your question: ***(it) returns a number representing the Unix Epoch***.

Comment: neither `"Fri Feb 26 2016 21:45:32 GMT-0500 (EST)".toNumber` nor `"Fri Feb 26 2016 21:45:32 GMT-0500 (EST)".valueOf()` are `1456541132899`, though, so this is not an answer

Comment: I've never heard of `toNumber` function/property. However, `valueOf()` and `Number()` functions give the same value. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uf5mgnty/).

Comment: Yes, your fiddle is obvious for the Date object in question, not the string object in my comment -- you will find that `"Fri Feb 26 2016 21:45:32 GMT-0500 (EST)".toNumber` is not `1456541132899`

Comment: There was no string objects in the question. The string won't be considered a date unless it's parsed by the Date class.