# MailAddress in .NET

Tags: .net, mailaddress

I'm attempting to send an email and instead of sending 5 individual emails to each person, I would like to send one mass email to all 5 people. The difference here is that I want everyone to show up in the "TO" or "CC" lines. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will send only one message:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("jdoe1@example.com", "Optional Name"));
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("jdoe2@example.com"));
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("jdoe3@example.com"));
msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress("jdoe4@example.com"));
msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress("jdoe5@example.com"));

// can add to BCC too
// msg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("jdoe5@example.com"));

msg.Body = "...";
msg.Subject = "...";

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Great example, but maybe it would help if you added using System.Net.Mail; and smtp.Host = "mail.mydomain.com"; or something of the sort so that users unfamiliar with the classes may be more successful with their implementations.

Comment: I prefer to have all my System.Net.Mail config handled in the web.config (see this answer for why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929/hidden-features-of-asp-net/75170#75170)

Comment: Silly me. I was actually doing this but I made a small mistake so I didn't realize it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Net.Mail;

...

MailMessage mmsg = new MailMessage();
mmsg.To.Add(new MailAddress("joe@user.com"));
mmsg.To.Add(new MailAddress("fred@user.com"));
mmsg.To.Add(new MailAddress("bob@user.com"));

// set other properties here...

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mymailserver.com");
client.Send(mmsg);
```

Edit:  aww, john's fingers are faster than mine ;)

Answer (score 2):

MailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(address))

Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.cc.aspx