# test sending emails from SharePoint without smtp server

Tags: sharepoint, email

I am trying to test SharePoint's sending of emails - whether basic alerts or custom code (calling SPUtility.SendEmail).  I tried specifying the smtpDeliveryMethod="pickup" as described here: [Hidden Features of ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929/hidden-features-of-asp-net/75170#75170) but it doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone gotten that method of testing Sharepoint's emails working?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using smtp4dev: http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I’m using Antix SMTP Server for Developers to test out my emails. It’s a dummy SMTP server which doesn’t send any real e-mails. But you still configure your SharePoint environment to use it as a SMPT-server, so you'll get a very realistic scenario.

url: http://www.antix.co.uk/Projects/SMTPServerForDevelopers.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't install on a machine w/o a live internet connection