# Can't access master page from user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

My master page code looks something like this:

```
namespace Recipes
{
    public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        ...

        public void UpdateUserLogin()
        {
            NicknameLbl.Text = ((Recipes.BasePage)Page).CurrentUser.Nickname;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

I want to call the `UpdateUserLogin()` method from a user control, something like this:

```
((Recipes.MasterPage)this.Page.Master).UpdateUserLogin();
```

But for some reason the compiler doesn't know `Recipes.MasterPage` (are you missing an assembly blablabla).
Sorry I can't show the exact error message, it's in French.

Maybe the problem is that I added the `Recipes` namespace around `MasterPage` manually, it wasn't added by VS.
By the way I'm using VS Web Developer Express 2008.

Do you have any idea how I can make this call work?

Comment: Is the usercontrol in the same project as the masterpage?

Answer (score 1):

Both the MasterPage and the UserControl are child controls of the page they are used by.  Your UserControl could potentially be used in a page that doesn't use your MasterPage, and so calling `UpdateUserLogin()` would not be valid.

You can check it like this, however, and make your call conditionally:

```
if (Page.Master is MasterPage)
{
    ((MasterPage)Page.Master).UpdateUserLogin();
}
```

**UPDATE**
It seems you were already aware of that, sorry.  Your question is about the reference not working.  What is the namespace of your UserControl?

Comment: The user control is in the `Recipes` namespace as well. I also added the namespace manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend data binding the NicknameLbl to the CurrentUser.Nickname property. Then the NicknameLbl text will get updated automatically if the property changes.

Answer (score 0):

1. include a MasterType directive at the top of the Content page ASPX file:

   '<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/DetailsMaster.master" %>'
2. include a public method in the Master page

   public void UpdateUserLogin(string value)
           {
               NicknameLbl.Text = value;
           }
3. access the method from the Content page using the Master syntax:

   Master.UpdateUserLogin(Some Text");

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Master_and_Contents.aspx

Comment: I do advice against using MasterType virtualpath, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998931/how-to-fix-namespace-problem-with-autogenerated-master-property-if-mastertype-is

Comment: @Bastien it's valid for control and I already use it and it work very good

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a Web Site Project (instead of a Web Application Project), then you do not have a project namespace. All code that is referenced from aspx.cs or master.cs files needs to be stored inside the App_Code directory, as the ASP.Net compiler will create several assemblies instead of just 1, and its not predictable which assembly will contain which aspx code.

Update after 1st comment:

The .ascx.cs and .aspx.cs stay where VS puts them. But it you want to reference classes etc, this needs to be placed inside App_Code, e.g. your Recipes.MasterPage or Recipes.BasePage objects.

Comment: Do you mean that .ascx.cs files (user control code files) should be in App_Code?