# ASP.Net Development Server performance

Tags: asp.net, performance, debugging, visual-studio-2008, webdev.webserver

I am developing a simple ASP.Net application on a Windows 7 x64 machine using Visual Studio 2008 SP1. The computer itself is a very strong machine.
I am using the built in development server for debugging.

Starting the debug process takes a mindblowingly long time (~20 minutes until the first page is loaded). Sometimes the pages load immediately. I encounter this problem only with web projects, windows forms project work as expected.

What could be the cause? How can I make the development work like it worked on an XP machine?

Edit:
The web pages are normal pages, no heavy code, so this cannot be the reason.

Comment: Do you have anything fired to your event log that could help debug this? You obviously have something messed up on your computer.

Comment: Is it that the browser itself is taking a long time to load the page?  Or is the dev server process itself just taking an abnormally long time to load?

Comment: You need to blow that machine away and "repave" it - reinstall the OS and the dev environment. You have something way screwed up, and no amount of tinkering is gonna fix it properly. On a side note, i would also check you don't have an anti virus prog scanning every single file that is generated as part of ASP.NET compiling your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is probably because on each change of a page, there is a batch compile of a lot of files, on the same directory. To avoid the batch compile use this flag on the `web.config`. That way only the changed file will be compile, the one you work on it, and not others.

```
<compilation batch="false" ... >
```

Relative : 
[Slow Performance -- ASP .NET ASPNET_WP.EXE and CSC.EXE Running After Clicking Redirect Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382741/slow-performance-asp-net-aspnet-wp-exe-and-csc-exe-running-after-clicking-red/2385097#2385097)

Answer (score 1):

try this fix for VS Studio 2008 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946581
This fix was not included in Microsoft Update. It fixes slow build time and many more and is recommended for users that experience problems.